# Explanation of [].slice.call in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, call, slice

I stumbled onto this neat shortcut for converting a DOM NodeList into a regular array, but I must admit, I don't completely understand how it works:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), 0)
```

So it starts with an empty array `[]`, then `slice` is used to convert the result of `call` to a new array yeah?

The bit I don't understand is the `call`. How does that convert `document.querySelectorAll('a')` from a NodeList to a regular array?

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'));` is a proper way to write the chunk of code you wrote.

Comment: BTW, the modern (and intuitively understandable) ES6 method for the same is  [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). So e.g. this would do the same: Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a'));

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how does Array.prototype.slice.call() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056925/how-does-array-prototype-slice-call-work)

Answer (score 189, accepted):

What's happening here is that you call `slice()` as if it was a function of `NodeList` using `call()`. What `slice()` does in this case is create an empty array, then iterate through the object it's running on (originally an array, now a `NodeList`) and keep appending the elements of that object to the empty array it created, which is eventually returned. Here's an [article on this](http://shifteleven.com/articles/2007/06/28/array-like-objects-in-javascript).

**EDIT:**

> So it starts with an empty array [], then slice is used to
>   convert the result of call to a new array yeah?

That's not right. `[].slice` returns a function object. A function object has a function `call()` which calls the function assigning the first parameter of the `call()` to `this`; in other words, making the function think that it's being called from the parameter (the `NodeList` returned by `document.querySelectorAll('a')`) rather than from an array.

Comment: Note too here that although this is semantically equivalent to saying `Array.prototype.slice.call(...)`, it actually instantiates an array object (`[]`) only to access its prototype slice method. That is a wasted instantiation. Saying `Array.prototype.slice.call(...)` instead is cleaner, although you add several characters to your JS if you're counting...

Comment: Note that this works in IE 8 and below only on Array objects, so you'll not be able to clone `NodeList`s

Comment: @quixoto `[]` is more reliable since `Array` could be overwritten to something else. If you need to reuse `Array#slice`, it’s a good idea to cache it.

Comment: In case anyone else is looking for a way to do this in IE8, check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199588/fastest-way-to-convert-javascript-nodelist-to-array

Comment: I actually saw this pattern appear in the backbone.js source code:  `var array = []; var push = array.push; var slice = array.slice; var splice = array.splice;` Does he do this for the safety issue @MathiasBynens mentions?

Comment: @MathiasBynens I believe it would be anti-pattern to overwrite Array it self, worse than creating prototype functions.

Answer (score 159):

In JavaScript, methods of an object can be bound to another object at runtime. In short, javascript allows an object to "borrow" the method of another object:

```
object1 = {
    name: 'Frank',
    greet() {
        alert(`Hello ${this.name}`);
    }
};

object2 = {
    name: 'Andy'
};

// Note that object2 has no greet method,
// but we may "borrow" from object1:

object1.greet.call(object2); // Will show an alert with 'Hello Andy'
```

The `call` and `apply` methods of function objects (in JavaScript, functions are objects as well) allows you to do this. So, in your code you could say that the NodeList is borrowing an array's slice method. `.slice()` returns another array as its result, which will become the "converted" array that you can then use.

Comment: Bang on  abstract concept explanation for javascript object's functions. 
Now, you can apply it for `call` function of `Array.prototype` aka `[].prototype` yourself.

Answer (score 34):

It retrieves the `slice` function from an `Array`. It then calls that function, but using the result of `document.querySelectorAll` as the `this` object instead of an actual array.

Answer (score 25):

It is a technique to convert array-like objects to real arrays.

Some of these objects include:

- [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) in functions
- [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (remember their content can change after being fetched! so converting them to array is a way to freeze them)
- jQuery collections, aka jQuery objects (some doc: [API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/), [type](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery), [learn](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/))

This serves many purposes, usually it is in order to use the [array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_methods).

Also, note the first argument `0` can be omited, [thorough explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286950/using-the-javascript-slice-method-with-no-arguments#11286982).

And for the sake of completeness, there is also [jQuery.makeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/).

Answer (score 21):

> How does that convert `document.querySelectorAll('a')` from a
>   `NodeList`  to a regular array?

This is the code that we have,

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), 0)
```

Lets dismantle it first,

```
  []    // Array object
.slice // Accessing the function 'slice' present in the prototype of Array
.call // Accessing the function 'call' present in the prototype of function object(slice)
(document.querySelectorAll('a'),0) 
    // 'call' can have arguments like, (thisArg, arg1,arg2...n). 
   // So here we are passing the 'thisArg' as an array like object,
  // that is a 'nodeList'. It will be served as 'this' object inside of slice function.
 // And finally setting 'start' argument of slice as '0' and leaving the 'end' 
// argument as 'undefined'
```

Step: 1 Execution of `call` function

- Inside `call`, other than the `thisArg`, the rest of the arguments
  will be appended to an argument list.
- Now the function `slice` will be invoked by binding its `this` value as
  `thisArg` (array like object came from `document.querySelector`) and with the argument list. i.e] argument `start` which contains `0`

Step: 2 Execution of `slice` function invoked inside of `call`

- `start` will be assigned to a variable `s` as `0`
- since `end` is `undefined`, `this.length` will be stored in `e`
- an empty array will be stored in a variable `a`
- After making the above settings the following iteration will be happened

  ```
  while(s < e) {
    a.push(this[s]);
    s++;
  }
  ```
- the filled up array `a` will be returned as the result.

---

P.S For better understanding of our scenario some steps that are necessary for our context has been ignored from the original algorithm of [call](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4) and [slice](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.10).

Comment: Very nice step by step explanation. Awesome! Thank you :)

Comment: Nice Explanation.

Answer (score 10):

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.slide'));
```

1. The querySelectorAll() method returns all elements in the document that matches a specified selector(s).
2. The call() method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually.
3. The slice() method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object.

so this line return the array of [object HTMLDivElement]. Here is the six div with classname "slide" so array length will be 6.

```js
var arraylist = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.slide'));
console.log(arraylist);
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slide">
    first slider1
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    first slider2
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    first slider3
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    first slider4
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    first slider5
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    first slider6
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

From ES6: Simply make array with **Array.from(element.children)** or **Array.from({length: 5})**

Answer (score 6):

We have for some time  been able to use

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.slide')]
```

and the more descriptive

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.slide'))
```

which is useful when you want to use map or filter on a nodelist or other *array-like* objects that do not have these methods.

It is however no longer needed when you use `forEach` since [forEach now works in all browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_nodelist_foreach) on the nodelist returned from `document.querySelectorAll('.slide')`

Answer (score 0):

This may help too.

### slice method

#### Description:

slice does not alter the original array. It returns a shallow copy of elements from the original array. Elements of the original array are copied into the returned array.

The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included) where start and end represent the index of items in that array. The original array will not be modified.
see more: [Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

### call method

#### Description:

The call() allows for a function/method belonging to one object to be assigned and called for a different object.

The call() method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually.
call() provides a new value of this to the function/method. With call(), you can write a method once and then inherit it in another object, without having to rewrite the method for the new object.

see more: [Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)