# In JavaScript, what is the best way to convert a NodeList to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

The DOM method `document.querySelectorAll()` (and a few others) return a `NodeList`.

To operate on the list, e.g. using `forEach()`, the `NodeList` must first be converted to an `Array`.

What's the best way to convert the `NodeList` to an `Array`?

Comment: I think the return value of querySelectorAll() is technically called a NodeList.

Comment: from [mdm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll)  "elementList = document.querySelectorAll(selectors);"

Comment: elementList is the variable name.  That same page describes how the type of the return value is a NodeList.

Comment: thanks for the correction - fixed in question

Comment: see also [Fastest way to convert JavaScript NodeList to Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3199588/1048572)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

With ES6 you can simply do:

```
const spanList = [...document.querySelectorAll("span")];
```

Comment: This gives me `Type 'NodeListOf<Element>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)`

Comment: Hi @callback, this seems like a TypeScript related error. You may have chosen to target es6 compilation without adding "es6" in the lib array of your tsconfig file. Regards

Comment: Hi @Freezystem, you are right! I am targetting es2015. Thanks!

Comment: @callback ES6 and ES2015 are the same thing

Comment: Just a heads up that **you don't need to convert a nodeList into an array to use forEach()** - see my answer below.

Comment: @callback I solved this by adding `"DOM.Iterable"` to the libs in the `tsconfig.json` file. It adds the `[Symbol.iterator]()` definition to many of the DOM types. See [this definition file](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/dom.iterable.d.ts).

Answer (score 91):

With ES6 you can use `Array.from(myNodeList)`. Then use your favourite array method.

```
var myNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.my-selector');

// ALT 1
Array.from(myNodeList).forEach(function(el) {
  console.log(el);
});
```

*Use an [ES6 shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim) to make this work in older browsers too.*

---

If you are using a transpiler (for example Babel) there are two more alternatives:

```
var myNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.my-selector');

// ALT 2
for (var el of myNodeList) {
  el.classList.add('active'); // or some other action
}

// ALT 3
[...myNodeList].forEach((el) => {
  console.log(el);
});
```

Comment: isn't also true under es6 that a nodeList supplies an iterator?

Comment: @ccyoung but the iterator doesn't work in non-compliant ES6 browsers because you can't shim Symbol object so it's better to use `Array.from(myNodeList)` because it can be shimmed.

Comment: so i have this issue where Array.from(el.childNodes) does not return the first node as part of the array.

Answer (score 55):

You can convert it to an array by using the `slice` method from the `Array` prototype:

```
var elList = document.querySelectorAll('.viewcount');
elList = Array.prototype.slice.call(elList, 0);
```

---

Furthermore, if all you need is `forEach`, you can invoke *that* from the `Array` prototype, without coercing it to an array first:

```
var elList = document.querySelectorAll('.viewcount');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elList, function(el) {
    console.log(el);
});
```

---

In ES6, you can use the new `Array.from` function to convert it to an array:

```
Array.from(elList).forEach(function(el) {
    console.log(el);
});
```

This is currently only in bleeding edge browsers, but if you're [using a polyfill service](http://cdn.polyfill.io/v1/docs/features/) you will have access to this function across the board.

---

If you're using [an ES6 transpiler](https://babeljs.io), you can even use a [`for..of`](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#iterators-for-of) loop instead:

```
for (var element of document.querySelectorAll('.some .elements')) {
  // use element here
}
```

Comment: thanks.  under newer javascript thought/hoping there was a more succinct coercion.

Comment: @cc young - Do note, the reason I'm using `Array.prototype.forEach` instead of `[].forEach`, is because the latter creates a new Array object, which is totally unnecessary.

Comment: @JosephSilber ahh thank you - that is the new array that's created is the empty `[]`? My thinking is that it would get garbage collected and the memory impact is negligible, can anyone comment on this?

Comment: @Daniel this is true, but there's still the computation of creating and destroying the array.

Answer (score 24):

Why convert? - just `call` function of Array directly on element collection  ;)

```
[].forEach.call( $('a'), function( v, i) {
    // do something
});
```

*assuming **$** is your alias for **querySelectorAll**, of course*

---

edit: ES6 allows for even shorter syntax `[...$('a')]` (*works in Firefox only, as of May 2014*)

Comment: Assuming `$` is `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Your answer implies jQuery usage. If that's the case, this tomfoolery is completely unnecessary, thanks to [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each).

Comment: lol, why ? nothing forbids you from making aliases like `function $ ( s )  { return document.querySelectorAll(s); }`.

Comment: The answer mentioned no such alias.

Comment: most succinct, despite your jQuery - think this is what I was looking for

Comment: forEach method is not a standard method from Array, Array.prototype.slice is

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, then the more succint solution is: `$('a').each(function(i, v) {...});`

Comment: offtopic: _EcmaScript 5 is a standard for a year already, all current-generation browsers support the new methods of Arrays, and question was specificly about using those methods on NodeList aka Element collection._

Answer (score 16):

### 2020 update: [nodeList.forEach() is now an official standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) and supported in all current browsers.

Older browsers can use the polyfill below.

> To operate on the list in javascript, e.g. using forEach(), the NodeList must be converted to an Array.

That's not true. `.forEach()` works in current browsers. If it's missing, you can use a polyfill to add .forEach() from **Array** to **NodeList** and it works fine:

```
if ( ! NodeList.prototype.forEach ) {
  NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

You can now run:

```
myNodeList.forEach(function(node){...})
```

To iterate over NodeLists just like Arrays.

This produces much shorter and cleaner code than .call() everywhere.

Comment: This answer was exactly what I needed and these 3 lines saved a lot of time. All the other answers would have required changing a bunch of code and I'm not understanding why.

Comment: downvotes were probably because monkey patching built-in prototypes is considered bad practice

Comment: @DuBistKomisch This is a polyfill, only applied if the standard NodeList.foreach() doesn't exist.

Comment: ah my bad, didn't realise they actually added `forEach` specifically, I came here looking for `filter`

Comment: @DuBistKomisch you can use the same technique for `filter`, but you may wish to give it an unofficial name `NodeList.prototype.dbkFilter` or similar if you're worried about a future standard using a different implementation .

Comment: For millions of people, IE11 is a current browser.

Answer (score 10):

Does it have to be `forEach`? You could simply use a `for` loop to iterate over the list:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elementList.length; i++) {
    doSomethingWith(elementlist.item(i));
}
```

Comment: +1 for going with the simple solution that doesn't add unnecessary array conversions.  FYI, Instead of `elementList.item(i)`, you could just use `elementList[i]`.

Comment: personally I find `forEach()` a better programming style and less verbose - ymmv

Comment: @cc young: Actually, I agree with you. Except in cases like this, where I would need to run a conversion just so I can use my favorite pattern. That makes it clunky and looks like: "When all you have is a hammer, everything starts to look like a nail."

Comment: And here is a nuttier way :)  `for (var oElement, i = 0; oElement = aMenuItemsElements; i++ {
console.log(oElement);
}`

Comment: Problem here is that you can’t nest another `for (var i…)` loop because the for loop doesn’t create its own scope (like it does in C/C++ now). And then the `i` get mixed up.

Answer (score 5):

Well, this works for me too:

```
const elements = Object.values( document.querySelector(your selector here) )
```

`Object.values()` returns `Array` of values of given object. `NodeList` is object, as is everything in JS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

But it's not compatible with IE, so i guess `Array.prototype.*array_method*.call(yourNodeList)` is the best option. With this you can invoke any array method on your `NodeList`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming *elems* is a nodeList:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select option:checked');
```

then it can be turned into an array as follows:

```
var values = [].map.call(elems, function(obj) {
  return obj.value;
});
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Example:_using_map_generically_querySelectorAll

Comment: One of the few answers that addresses the question

Answer (score 3):

That worked with me in ES6

lets assume you have nodelist  like that

```
<ul>
  <li data-time="5:17">Flexbox video</li>
  <li data-time="8:22">Flexbox video</li>
  <li data-time="3:24">Redux video</li>
  <li data-time="5:17">Flexbox video</li>
  <li data-time="7:17">Flexbox video</li>
  <li data-time="4:17">Flexbox video</li>
  <li data-time="2:17">Redux video</li>
  <li data-time="7:17">Flexbox video</li>
  <li data-time="9:54">Flexbox video</li>
  <li data-time="5:53">Flexbox video</li>
  <li data-time="7:32">Flexbox video</li>
  <li data-time="2:47">Redux video</li>
  <li data-time="9:17">Flexbox video</li>

</ul>


const items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-time]'));

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the following because I think it's easiest to read:

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('element');
[...elements].forEach((element) => {
   // code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

ES6 allows cool ways like `var nodeArray = Array.from(nodeList)` but my favorite one is the new spread operator.

```
var nodeArray = Array(...nodeList);
```

Comment: A perfect solution !  This solution applies for Typescript too.

Comment: I would like to add that this only works with TypeScript as long as you're not transpiling to ES5 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript version:

```js
const allDayElements: Element[] = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('span'));
```