# SCRIPT438 Error in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, foreach

I've been working on JavaScript lately, and everything was fine until I opened my page in **IE11**. as per [Mozilla website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) `.forEach` is supported from IE9.

This is the error I got.

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'

and this is the code.

```
var link1 = document.querySelectorAll("nav a");
    var textbox = document.getElementById("OutputWindow");
    link1.forEach(function (element) {
        textbox.innerHTML += "<br/>" + element + "\n";
        element.onclick = function () {
            alert("Hello!");
            console.log("hello!");
            confirm("Hello!");
        };
    });
```

I tried polyfill, but to my amusement, `Array` has a `forEach` in **IE11**.

Then where I'm going wrong?

**PS:** This works fine in Chrome.

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Quentin I cannot accept my own answer within 2-days. Or so the error says.

Comment: So wait a couple of days. Just don't edit the title of the question to include the word "Solved".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Finally mystery solved.

Apparently, IE9 and above supports `Array.forEach` but not for `NodeList`, which `querySelector` returns. I tried `Array.from()` to no avail as it requires *ES6* or use *ES6-shim*.

All I had to do was to convert from `nodeList` to `Array`, and I did by this.

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("nav a"), 0);
```

as appeared in question [In Javascript, what is the best way to convert a NodeList to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459704/in-javascript-what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-nodelist-to-an-array)

Comment: And everything "worked" fine in other browsers? That should not be possible.

Comment: Hmm... Something seems to have been changed recently. [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) used to return a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) (which doesn't support `forEach`), but currently it returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) instead.

Comment: @Teemu yea. It returns `NodeList` and Chrome has `forEach` support for `NodeList`

Comment: Actually, [per standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist), it shouldn't ... But the practice says else, hence this is what we're going with from now on.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (typeof Array.prototype.forEach != 'function') {
Array.prototype.forEach = function (callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        callback.apply(this, [this[i], i, this]);
    }
 };
}

if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
 }
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid changing the code for every `forEach()` call, here's a polyfill that worked for me. It's simple and recommended within https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach when running `forEach()` on a `NodeList`.

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this was the solution for me.  I hate IE.

Answer (score 3):

I was doing so:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(someElements))
```

The asnwer for me was simply that:

```js
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
   NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

Making sure that forEach also exists in Nodelist.