# Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach' in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function and it doesn't work in IE11. Display me this error in the forEach. In chrome and firefox work fine. Please help.

> Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'

```js
function someFunction(event) {
  var classList = event.currentTarget.classList.toString();
  var targetClass = classList.toString().slice(classList.indexOf('open'));
  $('button').removeClass('active');

  var toOpen = document.getElementsByClassName(targetClass);
  var _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
  var _didIteratorError = false;
  var _iteratorError = undefined;

  for (var _iterator = toOpen[Symbol.iterator](), _step
      ; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done)
      ; _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
    var el = _step.value;

    var childPanels = el.querySelectorAll('.fa');
    childPanels.forEach(function (child) {
      child.classList.toggle('fa-minus');
      child.classList.toggle('fa-active');
    });
    
    var childPanels = el.querySelectorAll('.panel');
    childPanels.forEach(function (child) {
      child.classList.toggle('current');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SCRIPT438 Error in Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41321515/script438-error-in-internet-explorer-11)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS ForEach Loops in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534102/js-foreach-loops-in-ie11)

Comment: Yes, I can’t remake my own, I don’t understand how to remake  :((( I already saw it, I can’t remake my own, it doesn’t work at all :(

Comment: Try like `Array.prototype.slice.call(childPanels).forEach(...)`

Comment: @Karan  please write your answer so that I can mark it. It's work , thanks

Comment: You can also add a polyfill `if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;}`

Comment: Snippet is from answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54344650/9695286 for which I have already mark question as duplicate. You can delete question or it should be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

forEach loops aren't supported by IE11, but you can easily get your own forEach :

For example, this :

```
childPanels.forEach(function (child) {
        child.classList.toggle('fa-minus');
        child.classList.toggle('fa-active');
});
```

will do the exact same thing than :

```
for (let idx = 0; idx < childPanels.length; i++) {
        childPanels[idx].classList.toggle('fa-minus');
        childPanels[idx].classList.toggle('fa-active');
}
```