# Find all @tagnames inside element then insert a link on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my html

```
<div class="comment-details">Hello @samplename This is my comment</div>
...
...
More .comment-details elements
```

On page load, I wanted to find this **@samplename** inside `.comment-details` class using `.each()` loop and insert it on `<a href="samplelink"></a>` tag in **jQuery** or **Javascript**

I wanted something like this after page load:

```
<div class="comment-details">Hello <a href="samplelink">@samplename</a> This is my comment</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery implementation:

```js
$('.comment-details').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\@.+?\b/g, `<a href=profile/${$(this).html().match(/\@.+?\b/g)[0].replace('@','')}>${$(this).html().match(/\@.+?\b/g)}</a>`));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment-details">Hello @samplename This is my comment</div>
<div class="comment-details">Hello @JG This is my comment</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to show the '@currentname' when already inserted in <a> tag. Not always '@samplename'

Comment: @MarkSalvania good spot sir mark. you can use `match` edited my answer

Comment: Almost :) how can I update `<a href="samplelink">` to `<a href="profile/currentname">` - without @ with `${$(this).html().match(/\@.+?\b/g)}` ?

Comment: No, it's based on what is on @tagname - this example has 'tagname' how to get it with `match`. Thank you

Comment: @MarkSalvania ah ok, you can just do another replace. replace @ with empty string

Comment: Perfect!. Thank you !. You completely answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

In raw JS you can do

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.comment-details')]
.forEach(tag => {
  tag.innerHTML = tag.innerHTML
    .replace(/\s?@(\w+)\s?/g, ' <a href="https://twitter.com/$1">@$1</a> ')
})
```

```html
<div class="comment-details">Wow @m0meni great answer</div>
<div class="comment-details">@m0meni a little self-congratulatory though</div>
```

Explaining each step:

- `querySelectorAll` grabs all the comment details divs
- `[...]` is because of [In Javascript, what is the best way to convert a NodeList to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459704/in-javascript-what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-nodelist-to-an-array)
- then you use the string replace function with a regular expression to do what you want

  - `/\s?@(\w+)\s?/g` grabs all the characters after @, and only does it if there's a space/nothing on either side i.e. hi@potoato wouldn't be matched
  - the $1 in the second argument uses the match from the replace

Comment: Works on windows desktop but not working on iphone safari :(

Comment: @MarkSalvania that’s probably because of the Array spread as it’s the only feature that might now work in older browsers.

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much!.

Comment: @MarkSalvania You could instead do `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.comment-details'), 0)` if that doesn't fix the issue...then sorry :'(