# Count number of columns in a table row

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table similar to:

```
<table id="table1">
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<table>
```

I want to count the number of td element in a row. I am trying:

```
document.getElementById('').cells.length;
document.getElementById('').length;
document.getElementById('').getElementsByTagName('td').length;
```

It did not show actual result.

Comment: By the following you can get the number of rows in a table:
document.getElementById('someid').getElementsByTagName('tr').length;

Comment: @pinouchon When one asks for a solution in Javascript, "you have to use jQuery" is not an answer.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('table1').rows[0].cells.length
```

cells is not a property of a table, rows are. Cells is a property of a row though

Comment: This only works in simple cases, where colspan=1 for all cells, and all rows have the same number of columns.  (HTML allows rows to have different numbers of columns, in which case the rows with too few columns get blanks at the end.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The question was about the cells in a row. If colspan=2 and missing two still means only one cell.

It gets a bit confusing when using rowspan though, but it still is correct, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GF6Dr/

If you want a number of how many cells in a table then do the max of all the cells.

Comment: The question title is "count number of **columns**". In his example, all of the `td`s have a colspan of 1, so counting the cells is sufficient. However, ignoring the colspan (number of **columns** a cell spans) is not a good idea if it's possible the colspan is anything besides `1`.

Answer (score 6):

You could do

```
alert(document.getElementById('table1').rows[0].cells.length)
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/TEZ73/

Answer (score 5):

Why not use reduce so that we can take colspan into account? :)

```
function getColumns(table) {
    var cellsArray = [];
    var cells = table.rows[0].cells;

    // Cast the cells to an array
    // (there are *cooler* ways of doing this, but this is the fastest by far)
    // Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15144269/6424295
    for(var i=-1, l=cells.length; ++i!==l; cellsArray[i]=cells[i]);

    return cellsArray.reduce(
        (cols, cell) =>
            // Check if the cell is visible and add it / ignore it
            (cell.offsetParent !== null) ? cols += cell.colSpan : cols,
        0
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad idea to count the `td` elements to get the number of columns in your table, because `td` elements can span multiple columns with `colspan`.

Here's a simple solution using jquery:

```js
var length = 0;
$("tr:first").find("td,th").each(function(){
 var colspan = $(this).attr("colspan");
  if(typeof colspan !== "undefined" && colspan > 0){
   length += parseInt(colspan);
  }else{
        length += 1;
  }
});

$("div").html("number of columns: "+length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>single</td>
  <td colspan="2">double</td>
  <td>single</td>
  <td>single</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div></div>
```

For a plain Javascript solution, see Emilio's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Count all **td** in table1:

```js
console.log(
table1.querySelectorAll("td").length
)
```

```html
<table id="table1">
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Count all td into each **tr** of table1.

```js
table1.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach(function(e){
 console.log( e.querySelectorAll("td").length )
})
```

```html
<table id="table1">
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a terse script taking into account `colspan`.

`numCols` will be 0 if the table has no rows, or no columns, and it will be equal to the number of columns regardless of whether some of the cells span multiple rows or columns, as long as the table markup is valid and there are no rows shorter or longer than the number of columns in the table.

```js
    const table = document.querySelector('table')
    const numCols = table.rows[0]
        ? [...table.rows[0].cells]
            .reduce((numCols, cell) => numCols + cell.colSpan , 0)
        : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, when you call `getElementById`, you need to provide an id.  o_O

The only item in your dom with an id is the `table` element.  If you can, you could add ids (make sure they are unique) to your `tr` elements.

Alternatively, you can use `getElementsByTagName('tr')` to get a list of `tr` elements in your document, and then get the number of tds.

[here is a fiddle that console logs the results...](http://jsfiddle.net/NNnMz/)

Answer (score 1):

If the `colspan` or `rowspan` is all set to `1`, counting the children `td`s will give the correct answer. However, if there are spans, we cannot count the number of columns exactly, even by the maximum number of `td`s of the rows. Consider the following example:

```js
var mytable = document.getElementById('table')
for (var i=0; i < mytable.rows.length; ++i) {
 document.write(mytable.rows[i].cells.length + "<br>");
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Header</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Hi</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Savings</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">hello</td>
            <td>world</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>hello</td>
            <td colspan="2">again</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="table1">
<tr>
  <td colspan=4><input type="text" value="" /></td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>

</tr>
<table>
<script>
    var row=document.getElementById('table1').rows.length;
    for(i=0;i<row;i++){
    console.log('Row '+parseFloat(i+1)+' : '+document.getElementById('table1').rows[i].cells.length +' column');
    }
</script>
```

Result:

```
Row 1 : 1 column
Row 2 : 4 column
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add table headers to each column in the table, you can count the number of table headers:

```
<table id="table1">
   <thead>
      <th></th>
      ...
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      ...
<table>
```

You can then count the number of columns by counting the number of table header elements (assuming each column has a table header element) using:

```
document.getElementById("table1").querySelectorAll("th").length
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#table1').find(input).length
```

Comment: describe your answer more detailed!