# Can't get the name of a column from an HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have tried so bad with no luck to get the name of a column of a table by using Javascript. I just want to get the text inside a th tag:

```
<th data-visible="false" id="th-0">The column name</th>
```

I have tried this:

```
var columna = document.getElementById('th-'+key).innerHTML;
```

And I just get either the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
```

or nothing when I try

```
var column = $('#th-'+key).text();
```

The key var comes fro ma loop because I am using bootstrap table where i want to show additional information if the user clicks on a plus button:

```
function detailFormatter(index, row) {
    var html = [];
    var columns_number=document.getElementById('table').rows[0].cells.length;/*http://stackoverflow.com/a/10043799/1883256*/
    console.log('The number of columns is: '+columns_number);
    $.each(row, function (key, value) {
        if(!isNaN(key)){/*http://stackoverflow.com/a/9716580/1883256*/
         console.log('Key value is: '+key);                    
         var column = $('#th-'+key).text();
                html.push('<p><b>' + key + ':</b> ' + value + ' - column: '+ column +'</p>');
        }
    });
    return html.join('');
}
```

Can anyone shed some light to fix this?

Comment: Your missing the '#' in your jquery selector

Comment: `$('#th-' + key).text()`

Comment: Oh yes, I have tried with and without and it does not work.

Comment: try logging the `key` variable to console just before calling `getElementById`.  I'm betting it's an issue with the value of that variable.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Key is displaying the number as it should for each element.

Comment: Can you add the HTML to your question and make a fiddle?

Comment: Not able to reproduce this one: https://jsfiddle.net/fkqdeLpz/

Comment: HTML would be nice.  Also having the javascript that calls `detailFormatter` would help too.

Comment: Same results: http://jsfiddle.net/5ae6g6b4/.  Can't reproduce.  Perhaps it's in how you are calling `detailFormatter`.  A lot depends on that unassuming little `row` parameter.

Comment: I have added the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/3139/). You will see a plus sign for more details of the row. I want to show the name of the columns and their values, just like [in this example](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/detail-view.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert `#` at begin of your selector, like this: `var columna = $('#th-'+key).text();`