# Count <td> in <tr> in multiple tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my View I have 4 tables.  I am using jQuery Datatables for each of the tables so for one of my records that I'm displaying in the view looks like this:

[image]

**WHAT I HAVE**

```
var countAllTablesRows = $("table tbody.teu-tbody tr").length;
console.log("Total Rows In Every Table on Page - " + countAllTablesRows);
var rowCountMinusOne = countAllTablesRows - 1;
console.log("Total Rows In Every Table on Page Minus One - " + rowCountMinusOne);
```

**MY GOAL**

When a user clicks the "Delete" link, I want to count all of the rows in each of the tables tbody elements.  However, I only want to count the table rows where there is actual data.. not the tables that have one row saying "No data available in table".

I was thinking of maybe using `.each()` to only get tables that don't contain "No data available in table", but I'm not sure of how to attack this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: May be similar to this, have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50650239/2494754

Comment: It would be nice to see your html.

Comment: Add a class on the rows (or table) with (`$("tr.hasData").length`) or without data (`$("tr:not(.hasNoData)").length`), or count the `Delete` links, use `.filter()` to count only rows with more than one column, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using DataTables, there are a few datatable API options to return the number of rows in your table.

[`rows().count()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/count()) is one way. This is handy if you want to get a count of table rows given specific circumstances, such as number of selected rows.

```
var table = $("#table-selector")
table.DataTable().rows().count()
```

[`.data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/data()) is another way. `.data()` returns all the data in the table as an array, from which you can simply call `.length` to get the length of the array.

```
var table = $("#table-selector")
table.DataTable().data().length
```

Both of the above methods work the same way. `.data()` simply returns all the data in the table, while `.rows()` may or may not return all data, as you can provide specific selectors to the `.rows()` function. In both cases, you can use `.length` or `.count()`. You have some flexibility.

As you have multiple tables, you can modify any of these to grab the data from all the tables all at once.

```
var table = $("#table-selector, #table-selector-two, #table-selector-three")
table.DataTable().rows().count()
```

This snippet will provide the count for tables #table-selector, #table-selector-two, and #table-selector-three. If you have a common class for all of them, this will work as well. You didn't provide your HTML, so I can only guess at how you are selecting your tables.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I added this in my question, but I only need the row count for the rows in the <tbody>.. not <thead>

Comment: If you are using DataTables, this shouldn't consider the header.

Comment: Okay, well I am using what you provided: `var allTables = $("table");
        var rowCount = allTables.DataTable().rows().count();
        console.log(rowCount);`  and I'm getting `8`.. the expected value should be 2

Comment: Do you have other tables that have been loaded into the DOM? `var allTables = $("table");` will load every table in the DOM, so thatwill throw off your results. It would be better if you had a more accurate selector, such as a parent div or maybe apply a class to each of the tables you want a count of.

Comment: I know for a fact that DataTables does not count the 'No Data' message and the headers as part of the `.count()` operation; I just tested it myself to be sure.

Comment: I added a class name and that did it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQuery '`:not`' and '`:contains`' to filter your rows, like this:

```
var countAllTablesRows = $("table tbody.teu-tbody tr:not:contains(No data)").length;
```

This will filter the rows, so only the rows not containing the text 'No data' will be counted.

Comment: I get red squiggly under data.. saying 'unexpected value'.  I need single quotes

Comment: Once I use your code, in the console I am receiving an error: **Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference**

Comment: Because it needs to be a subquote.  `$("table tbody.teu-tbody tr:not:contains('No data')")`