# Proper rows not getting colored

Tags: javascript, css

My rows are not getting colored properly"

Please have a look at my HTML output:

```
<table id="mytable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<tbody>
<tr class="tableheader">
<th>Name</th>
<th>Code</th>
<th>Value</th>
<th>Bid</th>
<th>Offer</th>
</tr>
<tr class="rowoddcolor">
<td>Apple</td>
<td>APPL</td>
<td>111</td>
<td>112</td>
<td>110</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tablecontent">
<td>Microsoft</td>
<td>MSFT</td>
<td>78</td>
<td>70</td>
<td>75</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rowevencolor">
<td>Google</td>
<td>GOGL</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>98</td>
<td>102</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tablecontent">
<td>Nokia</td>
<td>NOK</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rowoddcolor">
<td>Samsung</td>
<td>SAMS</td>
<td>89</td>
<td>86</td>
<td>90</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tablecontent">
<td>IntelCorporation</td>
<td>INTC</td>
<td>111</td>
<td>112</td>
<td>110</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now only the 1st and 5th row getting colored? why not 3rd row?

updated code:

```
function tablerows(id){
    if(document.getElementsByTagName){  
        var tableid = document.getElementById(id);  
        var rows = tableid.getElementsByClassName('tablecontent'); 
        for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){          
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                rows[i].className = "rowevencolor";
            }else{
                rows[i].className = "rowoddcolor";
            }      
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
                 $.getJSON('table.json',function(data){

                    $('#mytable').empty(); 
                    var html = '';
                    html += '<tr class="tableheader"><th>Name</th><th>Code</th><th>Value</th><th>Bid</th><th>Offer</th></tr>';
                    for (var i=0, size=data.length; i<size;i++) {                           
                            html += '<tr class="tablecontent"><td class="name">'+ data[i].name+ '</td><td class="code">'+ data[i].code+ '</td><td class="value">'
                                         + data[i].value+ '</td><td class="bid">'
                                         +data[i].bid+'</td><td class="offer">'+data[i].offer+'</td></tr>';
                            }

            $('#mytable').append(html);
            tablerows('mytable');

        });
    });
```

I am creating html through jquery consuming json. Table is getting created properly. Now through javascript, i am styling my alternate rows to different color and header should be in different color. This is my first question. Please see below my script:

```
function tablerows(id){
    if(document.getElementsByTagName){  
        var tableid = document.getElementById(id);  
        var rows = tableid.getElementById("tablecontent"); 
        for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){          
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                rows[i].className = "rowevencolor";
            }else{
                rows[i].className = "rowoddcolor";
            }      
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
                 $.getJSON('table.json',function(data){

                    $('#mytable').empty(); 
                    var html = '';
                    html += '<tr class="tableheader"><th>Name</th><th>Code</th><th>Value</th><th>Bid</th><th>Offer</th></tr>';
                    for (var i=0, size=data.length; i<size;i++) {                           
                            html += '<tr id="tablecontent"><td class="name">'+ data[i].name+ '</td><td class="code">'+ data[i].code+ '</td><td class="value">'
                                         + data[i].value+ '</td><td class="bid">'
                                         +data[i].bid+'</td><td class="offer">'+data[i].offer+'</td></tr>';
                            }

            $('#mytable').append(html);

        });

        $(function(){
            tablerows('mytable');
        });
    });
```

But my rows are not getting styled. Please tell me where is the problem.

Below is css code as well:

```
.rowoddcolor{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
.rowevencolor{
    background-color:#D3D3D3;
}
```

Comment: every row created should have unique Id,so use class instead of id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the function "tablerows" is getting executed before the build of table. So put that code after the append method.

**Example :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('table.json',function(data){
        // existing stuff
        $('#mytable').append(html);
        tablerows('mytable');
    });
});
```

Also the easiest way add the color class on alternating would be :

```
$('#mytable tr:even').addClass("rowevencolor");
$('#mytable tr:odd').addClass("rowoddcolor");
```

Comment: actually for coloring alternate rows, i have to use OO JS.

Comment: @user1814044, there is no problem in your code did you tried to put that function after append method?

Comment: @kundan-i used function after append. it is working. but not proper rows getting colored.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

First, Element ID's should be unique. Do not give every `tr` the same id `tablecontent`.

After that's fixed, you can ditch the entire helper function `tablerows()` as it is redundant and that logic can be moved to where you are building the table, i.e.:

```
for (var i=0, size=data.length; i<size;i++) {                           
    html += '<tr class="tablecontent row' + (i % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd') + 'color"><td class="name">'+ data[i].name+ '</td><td class="code">'+ data[i].code+ '</td><td class="value">'
         + data[i].value+ '</td><td class="bid">'
         + data[i].bid+'</td><td class="offer">'+data[i].offer+'</td></tr>';
}
```

Or simply use psuedo-selectors in your CSS as recommended by Kundan

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is not highlighting table row #3 is because the result of `getElementsByClassName` is a [NodeList, not an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach).

You will thus need to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199588/fastest-way-to-convert-javascript-nodelist-to-array) the NodeList to an Array before using the indexing operator for random access.

e.g.

```
    var rowsList = tableid.getElementsByClassName('tablecontent');
    var rows = Array.prototype.slice.call(rowsList);
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) 
       // ...
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxNft/2/)

However, as per Kundan's answer, it seems strange why you wouldn't use a jQuery solution, as it is much less work. jQuery fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fxNft/)

Comment: Hi Stuart. thanks for the fiddle. But now i am getting just 3 rows displayed instead of 6.

Comment: @user1814044 I can't simulate the JSON returned via ajax, but note that your updated example HTML above has incorrect TR class names. I've updated the jQuery fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fxNft/3/) and the Javascript fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fxNft/4/)

Comment: Thanks Stuart. Working perfectly fine now.