# querySelectorAll changing attributes

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

```
var p = document.getElementById(e),
   nodes = p.querySelectorAll('span');

   for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
      node = nodes[i];
      node.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
   }
```

If I make after console.log(p) and console.log(nodes), i see that the changes impacted nodes, but not p. Why and how to apply to p?

If i make `nodes = p.childNodes;` all works fine.

So, the main question, why it works with `childNodes` and doesn't work with `querySelectorAll`?

**UPDATED**

Finally, adding something like below can solve the issue:

```
for (var k=0; k<childNodes.length; k++) {
        for (var j=0; j<nodes.length; j++) {    
            if (childNodes[k].id === nodes[j].id) {
                p.replaceChild(nodes[j],childNodes[k]);
            } 
        }   
    }
```

Where `nodes = querySelectorAll` and `childNodes = p.childNodes`;

Comment: What is 'e'? What element does it refer to? You code affects all spans that are within the 'e' element.

Comment: imagine that `e` is `<div>` with different elements inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set the `innerHTML` of `p` directly:

```
p.innerHTML = '&nbsp';
```

Please note that [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll) "returns a non-live NodeList of all elements `descended` from the element on which it is invoked that match the specified group of CSS selectors."

So by default, the element you are calling this on `p` will not be included in the returned `NodeList`.

Comment: I don't understand... I have <div> with different elements there. I want to find all <span> inside that <div> and change the innerHTML for each of them.

Comment: @jagger - Your original question mentioned that the changes were **successfully** applied to all of the inner `<span>`s, but not to `p` itself. So my answer addresses setting the `innerHTML` of `p`.

Comment: Yes, that mean, that all the `<span>` in `nodes` are changed, but the same `<span>` in `p` are still not changed, but on my view they should be changed.
If i make `nodes = p.childNodes;`, all works correctly.

Comment: `<div><table>...</table>..<span>TEXT TO CHANGE</span>..<div></div></div>`

Comment: @jagger - Check out this working jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mvnCf/ . How does this differ from your code?

Comment: hm... it works and i don't understand why =) let me check my code again.

Comment: referring to your edit _So by default, the element you are calling this on p will not be included in the returned NodeList._, how i can avoid this?

Comment: Short answer is you **can't**. [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll) only returns `descended` elements.

Comment: All of the `<span>`s descended from `p` were affected, that is correct. But `p` **itself** was not affected.

Comment: Ok, well, but is there any trick to do? Like run over `p` after and check by `id` of elements, making `p[] = nodes[]`?

Answer (score 0):

Your NodeList should be converted to an array before using it.

[Fastest way to convert JavaScript NodeList to Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199588/fastest-way-to-convert-javascript-nodelist-to-array)

Comment: It's not, as in this case it will be static array and i need dynamically change it.