# Enumerate through elements returned by getElementByClassName in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following markups and scripts to simulate a simple calculator

HTML:

```
<input id="txtResult" type="text" readonly="readonly" /><br />
    <input id="txtInput" type="text" /><br />
    <button id="btn7" class="number">7</button>
    <button id="btn8" class="number">8</button>
    <button id="btn9" class="number">9</button><br />
    <button id="btn4" class="number">4</button>
    <button id="btn5" class="number">5</button>
    <button id="btn6" class="number">6</button><br />
    <button id="btn1" class="number">1</button>
    <button id="btn2" class="number">2</button>
    <button id="btn3" class="number">3</button><br />
    <button id="btnClear">C</button>
    <button id="btn0" class="number">0</button>
    <button id="btnClearEntry">CE</button><br />
    <button id="btnPlus">+</button>
    <button id="btnMinus">-</button>
```

Javascript:

The scripts tried to attach a click event handler to the buttons.

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("number");

    for (var btn in buttons)
    {
        console.log(btn); //print the value of "buttons", i.e 1, 2 ,3

        btn.addEventListener("click", numberClick, false);  // JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'
    }


    //However accessing an element directly works !!!
    var btn5 = document.getElementById("btn5");

    btn5.addEventListener("click", numberClick, false);
}

function numberClick()
{
    var input = document.getElementById("txtInput");
    input.value = input.value == "0" ? this.innerText : input.value + this.innerText;
}
```

The problem here is when I looped through the buttons and tried to attach the event handler, it threw an exception. However, when a button was retrieved directly by using getElementById, the code worked.

Could you please explain why?

Comment: `this.innerText` should be `this.textContent`

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: @bjb568 // JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nodeList is array-like, so a regular for loop should be used, and querySelectorAll has better support

```
window.onload = function() {

    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("number");

    for (var i=buttons.length; i--;) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", numberClick, false);
    }
}
```

When using for-in loops, it's

```
for ( key in object )
```

so it would be

```
for (var btn in buttons) {
    buttons[btn].addEventListener
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array like object that is better iterated like this:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", numberClick, false);
}
```

You can iterate arrays the way you were (not recommended though because it iterates all enumerable properties not just array elements which can sometimes mess up the code), but if you did, then `buttons[btn]` would be the object, not `btn` like you were trying to use.

Comment: Nobody cares about IE. Too terrible to support.

Comment: @bjb568 - actually, I don't think the return value from `getElementsByClassName()` supports `.forEach()` because it is a nodeList or HTMLCollection, not an array.

Comment: You could convert it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199588/fastest-way-to-convert-javascript-nodelist-to-array

Comment: nodeLists generally don't support array methods. every, some, forEach etc. doesn't work.

Comment: @bjb568 - yes you could convert it, but then why bother using `.forEach()`.  It doesn't buy you anything over a `for` loop if you have to add extra steps just to convert it into an array.

Comment: I didn't say you should do it. I just said it was an option.