# Return all classnames for use (outside a loop)

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

Is there a way to return all elements with a given classname for use outside a loop with JavaScript?

I mean, even if you use `querySelectorAll()`, if you are not in a foreach or an `i` loop, it won't do anything.

For example, you can do this:

```
var test = document.querySelectorAll(".test");
for (var i =0; i < test.length; i++) {

var allClasses = test[i]

// do stuff

}
```

However, this is less than ideal for more complicated functions, where you don't want to work inside the loop itself. Or you don't want to run loops in loops in loops.

The same goes foreach, you need to work inside the foreach function.

```
var test = document.querySelectorAll(".test");

[].forEach.call(test, function(t){
  var allClasses = t;
  // do stuff

});
```

So is there a simple function to return all classes as a variable for use? Or can you only store it in an array? Either way, how do you do it? Also how would you then use it?

Comment: Are you just asking how to convert the `NodeList` in `test` into an array?

Comment: Have you considered using JQuery? It does exactly that. http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: I'm trying to learn JavaScript, so I don;t want to use jQuery.

Comment: @Barmer, yes and also how to use that array quickly and simply

Comment: @LIUFA if it's not tagged jQuery, typically it's not the best idea to suggest it. It's more than often misused and bloats websites with code that is never called.

Comment: What do you want to do with the array? If you want to do anything with the elements in the array, you need to iterate over them.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199588/fastest-way-to-convert-javascript-nodelist-to-array for how to do the NodeList->array conversion.

Comment: Your code will only get the last value of the test array. If you want all the values then you could use an array and push the values to it.

Comment: @RUJordan One who is not aware of Jquery's existence would not put Jquery tag now would he?