# Javascript TypeError ____ is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am currently using the Chrome console to do some debugging for a Greasemonkey script.

From the console I run `var opp = document.querySelectorAll('a[class="F-reset"]');` and it works as expected.

But if I try to remove the first element with `opp.splice(0,1)` I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: opp.splice is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:5
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

If I try to run `opp[0].indexOf("a")`, i get the same thing.

How would I fix this?

Comment: What does `opp` return in the console? Undefined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is because the result of `querySelectorAll` is a node list, not an array. You can *apply* the slice method of `Array` to a node list, however:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(op, 0, 1);
```

This works more or less as expected, because a `NodeList` "quacks" in just the way `slice` expects, i.e. it contains elements indexed sequentially. However, you should be wary of using this in general; it is much safer to simply iterate over the `NodeList`.

Comment: _NodeList_ is guaranteed to be _Array-like_ and _slice_ is [_intentionally generic_](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.10) to work with _Array-likes_. There is nothing _"unsafe"_ here. **splice** though, probably won't work and is not safe on a _NodeList_.

Comment: @PaulS. Yes, *in the case of `Array` and `slice`*, this is perfectly safe. However, in general, unless you understand the underlying implementation well, you should avoid applying functions from the prototype of one object to another; if you're lucky you'll get an error, if you're unlucky you'll silently get unexpected behavior.

Comment: Slightly off topic, isn't opp.splice(0,1) supposed to _remove_ the first element? Your call is only returning the first element

Comment: @Bijan Yes, but I would say removing the first element from a `querySelectorAll` result is a useless operation. Just get the portion you're interested in. Perhaps if OP was splicing some portion in the middle it would make sense, but you can still do that with two `slice`s.

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`. This is similar to an array (it has a `.length` property and you can index it with `[]`), but it's not actually an array, and doesn't have most of the array methods. If you want to use array methods on an array-like object, you have to call the method explicitly:

```
Array.prototype.splice.call(opp, 0, 1);
```

or:

```
[].splice.call(opp, 0, 1);
```

However, another difference between arrays and `NodeLists` is that you can't modify `NodeList` in place, which `.splice` tries to do; you can only read them like arrays. You should just use `.slice()` to extract the parts you want. Or convert the `NodeList` to an array first, and then operate on that. See

[Fastest way to convert JavaScript NodeList to Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199588/fastest-way-to-convert-javascript-nodelist-to-array)

Comment: _querySelectorAll_ actually returns a _non-live NodeList_ (You are right that some _NodeLists_ can be _live_ though, just not here)

Comment: Also, [_splice_ is _intentionally generic_](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.12), but AFAIK you can't perform an assignment on a _NodeList_ so it will fail, `TypeError: Cannot set property length of #<NodeList> which has only a getter`. Solution? `slice` then `splice`

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I've updated my answer to remove the issue about live NodeLists and just talk about their non-modifiability.

Answer (score 0):

querySelector/All returns a NodeList not an array, so those functions are not available.

You can use `call` to use those array methods though

```
[].splice.call(opp,0,1);
```

The first argument is the execution context that the function will use, all other arguments are the arguments that will be passed to the function

[Function call reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Answer (score 0):

First,

- [`splice`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.12) is a method of *Arrays*, inherited through `Array.prototype`, although it is *intentionally generic* so can be called on other *Arraylike* objects
- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a *non-live NodeList*, this is not an *Array* and does not share any inheritance with *Array*, meaning you can't simply access *Array methods* through it
- A *function* can be invoked with a custom `this` via [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
- `splice` needs to be able to assign on it's `this`, which will fail for a *NodeList* as you will get the following `TypeError: Cannot set property length of #<NodeList> which has only a getter`
- Other  *intentionally generic Array methods* which only read from `this` will work on a *NodeList*, e.g. *slice, map, indexOf, forEach, filter, some, every, etc..*

Now we are in a position to do something,

1. Convert the *NodeList* to an *Array* and store this reference, i.e. with `Array.prototype.slice`
2. Perform your `splice` on this object instead

So,

```
var opp = document.querySelectorAll('a[class="F-reset"]'); // NodeList
oop = Array.prototype.slice.call(oop); // Array
// ...
oop.splice(0, 1);
```