# includeArray.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to match a substring of elements value to the url, in order to dynamically highlight the page the user is on.

I am positive that I have an array object of elements. I tested it in the window. Yet, I am getting an error `includeArray.filter` is not a function. Here is my code

```
var url = window.location.href;
url = url.replace("-", " ");
var includeArray = document.getElementsByClassName("includeHelper");
var subStringElem = includeArray.filter(function (obj) {
  var thisVal = obj.value
  if (url.indexOf(thisVal) != -1) {
    return true;
  }
  else { return false; }
});
```

What could I be doing incorrectly?

Comment: `filter` is array's method. `getElementsByClassName` returns collection of elements, not array.

Comment: @hindmost how are they different, the window shows [ node1, node2] etc. it looks like an array to me.

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199588/fastest-way-to-convert-javascript-nodelist-to-array
basically you can do `Array.prototype.slice.call(includeArray).filter..`

Comment: @Oriol That's right

Comment: @apieceofbart That worked