# Javascript loop over node array getting alternate entries

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

After creating an array with `document.getElementsByClassName()`, I want to change the `className` property of each element.  Individual elements can be accessed properly by using literal subscripts. However, when using a for loop, such as:

```
for (i = 0; i < myElements.length; i += 1) { ... }
```

I'm getting only alternate elements, which seems to defy what the `for` loop is doing. And after the `for` executes the processed elements are no longer in the array, which is also unintended.

I have loaded a test page at http://www.mwpnz.com/classes/page.htm
(This include extensive debug code to see what is happening)
Thank you.

Comment: In the future, particularly or an example that small, show us the full code inside the answer, and particularly the contents of the for-loop!!  Had you done that a much broader spectrum of people would have seen the problem and been able to help you.  Your debugging example was odd, and didn't really just show us the most essential thing we need to know.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the changes you're making are removing the class that you searched for.

`getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an array, it returns an `HTMLCollection`. And the collection is a *live* NodeList, which means that it automatically tracks changes in the DOM -- if you add/remove an element that matches the class, or add/remove the class name, the collection updates itself.

What this means is that if you remove the class from one of the elements while you're looping, it will be removed from the collection, and the indexes of all the following elements will shift down. Then when you increment the index, you'll skip over the element that shifted into the place that you just operated on.

The simple solution is to convert the collection to an array first. In ES6 you can use `Array.from()`.

```
var elementArray = Array.from(nodeList);
```

For older browsers, use

```
var elementArray = [].slice.call(nodeList);
```

See [Fastest way to convert JavaScript NodeList to Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199588/fastest-way-to-convert-javascript-nodelist-to-array)

Answer (score 1):

`.getElementsByClassName` returns a *live* nodeList, i.e. if you select the elements that have `A` className and then remove the `A` className from one of the elements then the `.length` property of the collection is changed.

Check this example:

[image]

You can convert the nodeList to a regular array by using the following code:

```
var nodeArr = Array.prototype.slice.call( myElements );
```

Comment: I hadn't realised that the selection expression of the nodelist was retained and re-evaluated, so great to learn that.
A while (nodelist.length > 0) change element[0]  avoids creating the array, although probably isn't as efficient.

Answer (score 1):

save a copy of myElements, and iterate over the new array. Such as:

```
myElements = document.getElementsByClassName("v1");
newArray = Array.from(myElements);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the assistance of the above information, this is now working fine, using

```
myElements = document.getElementsByClassName("v1");
while (myElements.length > 0) {
  // this will remove  myElements[0]  from the myElements nodelist
  myElements[0].className = myElements[0].className.replace("v1","vh1");
}
```