# RegExp. Get only text content of tag (without inner tags)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have string with html code.

```
<h2 class="some-class"> 
   <a href="#link" class="link" id="first-link"
      <span class="bold">link</span>
   </a>
   NEED TO GET THIS
</h2>
```

I need to get only text content of h2.
I create this regular expression:

```
(?<=>)(.*)(?=<\/h2>)
```

But it's useful if h2 has no inner tags. Otherwise I get this:

```
   <a href="#link" class="link" id="first-link"
      <span class="bold">link</span>
   </a>
   NEED TO GET THIS
```

Comment: That's not even valid HTML

Comment: Are you restricted to Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rgex is not good for parsing HTML, but if your html is not valid or any way you like to use regex:

```
(?!>)([^><]+)(?=<\/h2>)
```

[try Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WctM1O/2)

- It's getting last texts before closing tag of `</h2>` *(IF EXISTS)*
- To avoid `null` results changed `*` to `+`.
- This Regex is completely **limit** and fitting to **limited situations** as question mentioned.

Comment: I know @ThomasAyoub , but I think Question was about to select the text just before closing tag.

Comment: And I've mentioned in my answer: It's getting last texts before closing tag of `</h2>`. so sending down vote for all answers is not true answer! @ThomasAyoub

Comment: 1) I didn't vote you down 2) Even if I did, that's my right because I consider your answer as incorrect. 3) You're the only one with down vote on this page. Now have a nice day Sir.

Answer (score 3):

Never use regex to parse HTML, check these famous answers:

[Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

---

Instead, generate a temp element with the text as HTML and get content by filtering out text nodes.

```js
var str = `<h2 class="some-class"> 
   <a href="#link" class="link" id="first-link"
      <span class="bold">link</span>
   </a>
   NEED TO GET THIS
</h2>`;

// generate a temporary DOM element
var temp = document.createElement('div');
// set content
temp.innerHTML = str;
// get the h2 element
var h2 = temp.querySelector('h2');

console.log(
  // get all child nodes and convert into array
  // for older browser use [].slice.call(h2...)
  Array.from(h2.childNodes)
  // iterate over elements
  .map(function(e) {
    // if text node then return the content, else return 
    // empty string
    return e.nodeType === 3 ? e.textContent.trim() : '';
  })
  // join the string array
  .join('')
  // you can use reduce method instead of map
  // .reduce(function(s, e) { return s + (e.nodeType === 3 ? e.textContent.trim() : ''); }, '') 
)
```

Reference :

[Fastest way to convert JavaScript NodeList to Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199588/fastest-way-to-convert-javascript-nodelist-to-array)

Comment: While I agree with the fact that one shouldn't use regex to parse HTML, OP just want to get `NEED TO GET THIS`

Comment: @ThomasAyoub : oops sorry, updating

Comment: `e.nodeType === 3`?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub : to check text node or not

Comment: Got it, thanks. For future readers, [direct link to nodeType doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)

Answer (score 1):

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/frun22k5/)

```
var h2 = document.querySelector('h2')

var h2_clone = h2.cloneNode(true)

for (let el of h2_clone.children) {
    el.remove()
}

alert(h2_clone.innerText)
```

Comment: Do you know that SO have integrated fiddle?