# Using querySelectorAll on checkboxes to display an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, checkbox

My idea is when you hover checkbox number 1, the same index number will display the same car from the same position.

```
var carArray = ["Bmw", "Volvo", "Ferrari", "Audi", "Volkswagen", "Honda"];
```

So if I hover over the first checkbox it will log `"Bmw"`, if I hover over the fourth, `"Audi"` will be logged.

```js
var carArray = ["Bmw", "Volvo", "Ferrari", "Audi", "Volkswagen", "Honda"];
var chb = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");

for (var i = 0; i < chb.length; i++) {
  chb[i].addEventListener("mouseover", test);
}

function test() {
  console.log(carArray[i]);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div><input type="checkbox"> 1</div>
<div><input type="checkbox"> 2</div>
<div><input type="checkbox"> 3</div>
<div><input type="checkbox"> 4</div>
<div><input type="checkbox"> 5</div>
<div><input type="checkbox"> 6</div>
```

Comment: well `i` is just whatever it is after the loop is done.... Your code is basically `var i = chb.length; function test(){
  console.log(carArray[i]);
}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Why not store the the car names in the value of each input. <input value="BMW" type="checkbox">1

Then just get the .val() of each element as it's hovered over.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var carArray = ["Bmw", "Volvo", "Ferrari", "Audi", "Volkswagen", "Honda"];
var chb = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");

chb.forEach((x,i) => x.addEventListener("mouseover", () => test(i)))

const test = i => console.log(carArray[i]);
```

Issue with your code is that `i` is by the time passed to your event handler already at `6` value.

```js
var carArray = ["Bmw", "Volvo", "Ferrari", "Audi", "Volkswagen", "Honda"];
var chb = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");

chb.forEach((x,i) => x.addEventListener("mouseover", () => test(i)))

function test(i) {
  console.log(carArray[i]);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div><input type="checkbox"> 1</div>
<div><input type="checkbox"> 2</div>
<div><input type="checkbox"> 3</div>
<div><input type="checkbox"> 4</div>
<div><input type="checkbox"> 5</div>
<div><input type="checkbox"> 6</div>
```

Comment: instead of referring to `carArray[i]` i would suggest using the `event.target` from the `event` param passed into the event handler method.

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList, there are lot's of ways you can convert it to an array:

```
Array.from(querySelectorAll('query'));
```

There's a SO thread showing various ways to handle this:

[Fastest way to convert JavaScript NodeList to Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199588/fastest-way-to-convert-javascript-nodelist-to-array)

Comment: NodeList implements the iterable protocol, and therefore you can do `for..of` loops easily without converting to an array