# Calling a function with several array paramaters

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Having a list of HTML anchors, I need to add Event listener, which as I understand is not recieving array when I mention it as parameter.

As a try, instead of extra functions I used self-calling, but this way even `i` wasn't listened when debugging.

```
for (var i=0; i < anc.length; i++) {
    anc[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(i,pop,tri) {
       console.log('i=%i', i);    // last value of loop
       pop[i].style.display = 'initial';
       tri[i].style.animation='anim_dpt_tr 0.4s ease-out forwards';
    });
    ...
}
```

A more useful code

```
var pop = document.querySelectorAll('#cities > li > a > .popup');
const anc = document.querySelectorAll('#cities > li > a');
var tri = document.getElementsByClassName('triangle-left');

for (var i=0; i < anc.length; i++) {
    anc[i].addEventListener('mouseover', over(i, tri, pop));
    anc[i].addEventListener('touchmove', over(i, tri, pop));
    anc[i].addEventListener('touchend', out(i, tri, pop));
    anc[i].addEventListener('mouseout', out(i, tri, pop));
}

function over(i,tri,pop) {
    console.log("over_address=%i", pop[i]); // =0
    pop[i].style.display = 'initial';
    tri[i].style.animation='anim_dpt_tr 0.4s ease-out forwards';
}
function out(i,tri,pop) {
    console.log("out_i=%i", i);             // =each index
    pop[i].style.display = 'none';
    tri[i].style.animation='anim_dpt_tr_back 0.3s ease-in forwards';
}
```

here HTML tree

```
<ul id="cities">
  <li>
    <a href="">Shoulder
      <span class="triangle-left"></span> <span class="popup">Arm</span> </a>
  </li>
...
```

How to pass arrays correctly to Event handler?

Comment: IIRC, `.querySelector()` returns a NodeList, NOT an array -- you may need to convert it to an array before doing array type work against the elements. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199588/fastest-way-to-convert-javascript-nodelist-to-array )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `anc[i].addEventListener('anyEvent', over(i, tri, pop))` will try to immediately invoke the function. Instead you can create a callback function and call the `over` & `out` from that. Also instead of passing multiple parameter pass the context using `this`. Here `this` will refer to the element which is triggering the event that is the `anchor tag` in this case.

Then inside the `over/out` function use `elem.querySelector('.popup')` which will target an element with `popup` class inside the element which is triggering the event . Then you can add the style properties

```js
const anc = document.querySelectorAll('#cities > li > a');
for (var i = 0; i < anc.length; i++) {
  anc[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    over(this)
  });

  anc[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    out(this)
  });
}

function over(elem) {
  elem.querySelector('.popup').style.display = 'initial';
  elem.querySelector('.triangle-left').style.animation = 'anim_dpt_tr 0.4s ease-out forwards';
}

function out(elem) {
  elem.querySelector('.popup').style.display = 'none';
  elem.querySelector('.triangle-left').style.animation = 'anim_dpt_tr_back 0.3s ease-in forwards';
}
```

```html
<ul id="cities">
  <li>
    <a href="">Shoulder
      <span class="triangle-left"></span> <span class="popup">Arm</span> </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Shoulder
      <span class="triangle-left"></span> <span class="popup">Leg</span> </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Shoulder
      <span class="triangle-left"></span> <span class="popup">ercerc</span> </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's a Snickers, @brk! You answer even includes a demonstration.
I have chosen your variant as answer 'cause is't mostly smart and your explication of methods is more reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

Your "more useful code" is incorrect because it doesn't actually assign any event handlers; it just invokes the code immediately and returns `undefined`.

To take that approach, you'd have those functions return a function. That's where you'd define the event parameter.

```
function over(i,tri,pop) {
  return function(event) {
    console.log("over_address=%i", pop[i]); // =0
    pop[i].style.display = 'initial';
    tri[i].style.animation='anim_dpt_tr 0.4s ease-out forwards';
  }
}
function out(i,tri,pop) {
  return function(event) {
    console.log("out_i=%i", i);             // =each index
    pop[i].style.display = 'none';
    tri[i].style.animation='anim_dpt_tr_back 0.3s ease-in forwards';
  }
}
```

This is an old-school way of doing it. More recently, you'd use an `i` variable that's scoped to the `for` loop's block by using `let` or `const` instead of `var`.

---

Another thing to consider is if it's really worth it to cache the collections. If there's a pretty simple relationship in the layout between each `i` element in each collection, then DOM traversal inside the handler may be preferred.

---

Yet another possibility is to create an object that implements the *EventListener* interface. Then you can just assign each element to the object, and use the object itself in lieu of an event handler function.

```
var pop = document.querySelectorAll('#cities > li > a > .popup');
const anc = document.querySelectorAll('#cities > li > a');
var tri = document.getElementsByClassName('triangle-left');

for (var i=0; i < anc.length; i++) {
    // Create a new instance of your object, giving it the data needed
    //   when an event occurs.
    var obj = new MyElements(pop[i], anc[i], tri[i], i);

    // Use the object itself in lieu of an event handler function
    //  (see below)
    anc[i].addEventListener("mouseover", obj);
    anc[i].addEventListener("touchmove", obj);
    anc[i].addEventListener("mouseout", obj);
    anc[i].addEventListener("touchend", obj);
}

// Holds the relevant info for each index
function MyElements(pop, anc, tri, i) {
  this.pop = pop
  this.anc = anc
  this.tri = tri
  this.i = i
}

// Implements the EventListener interface.
// This is what gets invoked when an event occurs.
// It is set up to simply invoke a function on the same object
//   that has been given the same name as the event.
MyElements.prototype.handleEvent = function(event) {
  this[event.type](event)
}

// These are the functions for each event type. For simplicity, I
// gave each handler the name of the event that fires it so that
// you can use event.type to invoke them.
MyElements.prototype.mouseover = 
MyElements.prototype.touchmove = function over(event) {
    console.log("over_address=%i", this.i); // =0
    this.pop.style.display = 'initial';
    this.tri.style.animation='anim_dpt_tr 0.4s ease-out forwards';
}

MyElements.prototype.mouseout =
MyElements.prototype.touchend = function out(event) {
    console.log("out_i=%i",this.i);             // =each index
    pop[i].style.display = 'none';
    tri[i].style.animation='anim_dpt_tr_back 0.3s ease-in forwards';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use .bind() to get this done. All your calls could look like, for e.g. `over.bind(null, i, tri, anc)`, when used as a function handler. Notice, a required `null` as the first argument.

Therefore, that would transform to :

```
over.bind(null, i, tri, pop)
out.bind(null, i, tri, pop)
```

Let me know if that works. Else, leave me a comment.