# How to fix the 'map is not a function' error in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm  looping through all anchor tag in an HTML with a class (.add-to-cart) to change text content to shop now, using map() but i am getting an error that says .map is not a function.

```
<!--HTML CODE -->
 <div class="four columns">
        <div class="card">
                <a href="#" class="u-full-width button-primary button input add-to-cart" data-id="5">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>
</div> <!--.card-->
<div class="four columns">
        <div class="card">
                <a href="#" class="u-full-width button-primary button input add-to-cart" data-id="5">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>
</div> <!--.card-->
<div class="four columns">
        <div class="card">
                <a href="#" class="u-full-width button-primary button input add-to-cart" data-id="5">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>
</div> <!--.card-->


//JAVASCRIPT CODE
const addCartBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.add-to-cart');


addCartBtns.map(function(cartBtn){
  console.log(cartBtn.textContent="shop now");
});
```

I expect the output to change text content of anchor tags to "shop now".

Comment: If you're not going to use the return value of `.map()` than you shouldn't be using `.map()`. In your case you should be using `.forEach()` - and with a modern browser this will already be available on the [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` which should be converted to real `Array` before using `map()`

> The Document method `querySelectorAll()` returns a static (not live) `NodeList` representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors

You can use Spread Operator

```
const addCartBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll('.add-to-cart')]
```

Or you can can use `Array.from`

```
const addCartBtns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.add-to-cart'))
```

Notice that you are using `map()`. `map()` is used when you want to create a new array bases on the values of existing array of same length. Here you are modifying the array. So you can use `forEach`

```
addCartBtns.forEach(function(cartBtn){
  console.log(cartBtn.textContent="shop now");
});
```

**Note**:`forEach` will work fine if `NodeList` is not converted to array.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you don't actually need `map`, `forEach` will do, and NodeList has a `forEach`. Therefore:

```
addCartBtns.forEach(function(cartBtn) {
  console.log(cartBtn.textContent="shop now");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use map simply because the output from querySelectorAll is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) object, not Array. If you want to loop every item in the NodeList, you should use forEach instead.

Take a look at the NodeList API documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

---

However you can quickly convert NodeList object to Array
[Fastest way to convert JavaScript NodeList to Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199588/fastest-way-to-convert-javascript-nodelist-to-array)

```
[...addCartBtns]

Array.prototype.slice.call(addCartBtns);

Array.from(addCartBtns)
```