# Store two user number inputs in variables, validate as numbers, and write total sum of the two digits

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form created in html, with two input fields and one button. When clicking on the button i want a function to be called for that will then add the two numbers and then display the sum via the alert function.

I know how to call for the function when the button is clicked, and i know how to read and store the two inputs in separate variables.

I would like some tips on how to in the easiest way validate the input as numbers only?

```
function Calculate() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;

  var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  num1_parsed = parseInt(num1);    

  num2_parsed = parseInt(num2);

  if (num1_parsed) {    

  } else {
    alert("Wrong input!!!");
    return false;    
  }

  var total = num1_parsed + num2_parsed;
  alert("The total sum of your numbers are: " + sum);
}
```

This code works for some reason, tho if num1 is correct but num2 is not it gives message NaN instead of the alert message!

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript Method**

With JavaScript doing the validation, you can use the isNaN() function. This will return true if the input is not a number.

```
function Calculate() 
{
  var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;

  num1_parsed = parseFloat(num1);    
  num2_parsed = parseFloat(num2);

  if(isNaN(num1_parsed) || isNaN(num2_parsed))
  {
      alert("Wrong input!!!");
      return false;
  } else {
      var total= num1_parsed + num2_parsed;
      alert("The total sum of your numbers are: " + total);
      return true;
  }
}
```

**HTML5 Method**

Additionally, if you wish to use HTML5 only to ensure the input values are number's then you can use the type="number" attribute to the input tag.  This adds built-in validation to reject non-numerical numbers.

```
<input type="number" id="num1" />
<input type="number" id="num2" />
```

Comment: I suspect that properly implementing javascript validation is the actual lesson goal here.

Comment: Still have to cast values to number. A `type="number"` still returns string value

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an input element as `type="number"`

```
num1_parsed = Number(num1);
num2_parsed = Number(num2);

if (isNaN(num1_parsed) || isNaN(num2_parsed) ) {
    alert("Wrong input!!!");
    return false;
} else {
    // do stuff
    return true;        
}
```

Comment: You have the logic in reverse `isNaN` returns true if the value is not a number

Comment: @ZohirSalak oops!

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="number" id="num1" />
<input type="number" id="num2" />
<button onClick="Calculate()" type="button">Get Sum</button>
```

JS

```
function Calculate() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;

  var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  num1_parsed = parseFloat(num1);    

  num2_parsed = parseFloat(num2);

  if (isNaN(num1_parsed) || isNaN(num2_parsed) ) {    
     alert("Wrong input!!!");
     return false;    
  }

  var total = num1_parsed + num2_parsed;
  alert("The total sum of your numbers are: " + total);
}
```

OR

```
function Calculate() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;

  var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  if( !num1 || !num2 ){
     alert("please enter values for num1 and num2");
  } 
  var total = eval(`${num1}+${num2}`);
  if( isNaN(total) ){
     alert("Wrong input!!!");
     return false;    
  }
  alert("The total sum of your numbers are: " + total);
}
```

Comment: Yes, what if num1 or num2 is empty ? [also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10474316/7148391)

Comment: if any num is empty parseFloat will return "NaN" object

Comment: if one of the values is empty the eval returns the other one

Comment: for that you can add check for that before eval

Answer (score 0):

Using isNaN() function.  It might be more readable to use || instead of && which would mean that the result would be false.

```js
function Calculate() {

  var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  
  num1_parsed = parseInt(num1);    
  num2_parsed = parseInt(num2);
  
  
 //console.log((!(isNaN(num1_parsed))).toString() + " " + num1_parsed);
 //console.log((!(isNaN(num2_parsed))).toString() +  " " + num2_parsed);

  if (!(isNaN(num1_parsed)) && !(isNaN(num2_parsed))){
  var total = num1_parsed + num2_parsed;
  alert("The total sum of your numbers are: " + total);
  
  } else {
alert("Wrong input!!!");
    return false;        
  }


}
```

```html
<input id="num1" />
<input id="num2" />
<button onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

You can use `map` combined with `Number` to perform the initial transform. Afterwards using `reduce` can give you the `total`. Then you simply check if any of the `numbers` equal `NaN`.

---

### Code:

```
  let num = (n) => document.getElementById("num" + n).value,
    total = (numbers = [num(1), num(2)].map(Number)).reduce((a, v) => a + v);

  if (numbers.some(Number.isNaN)) alert("wrong");
  else alert("The total sum of your numbers are: " + total);
```

*Note*: It's important to realize that `isNaN` and `Number.isNaN` are **different** and will sometimes give different results. `Number.isNaN` specifically looks to see if a value is a `number` and if that `number type` is `NaN`. `isNaN` will coerce the supplied `value`. A.e. `isNaN(undefined)` and `Number.isNaN(undefined)` return `true` and `false` respectively.

---

### Demo:

```js
function Calculate() {
  let num = (n) => document.getElementById("num" + n).value,
    total = (numbers = [num(1), num(2)].map(Number)).reduce((a, v) => a + v);

  if (numbers.some(Number.isNaN)) alert("wrong");
  else alert("The total sum of your numbers are: " + total);


}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", Calculate);
```

```html
<input id="num1" value="34" />
<input id="num2" value="100" />
<hr/>
<button>Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

With modern HTML one can validate the two inputs without having to check for empty or invalid inputs.

### 1. no need to check for empty input

Checking for empty inputs is taken care of by the [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#required) attribute:

> *A number input is considered valid when empty and when a single number is entered, but is otherwise invalid. If the `required` attribute is used, the input is no longer considered valid when empty.* ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#a_simple_number_input))

### 2. no need for parsing inputs with `parseInt`

By using [input elements of type `number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

```
<input id="num1" type="number" required/>
<input id="num2" type="number" required/>
```

the inputs are valid if they're numbers. Note that in general a number can be a float but since the [`step`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#step) attribute is not specified it is by default `1` thus allowing only integers to be entered.

Also note that negative integers are allowed unless one uses `min=0`.

### Demo

```js
document.forms["myform"].addEventListener('submit',
  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log();
    const sum = [...document.querySelectorAll("[type='number']")]
      .map(x => (+x.value))
      .reduce((a, c) => a + c);
    alert(`The sum is ${sum}`);
  }
)
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  <input id="num1" type="number" required/>
  <input id="num2" type="number" required/>
  <input type="submit" value="Calculate sum" />
</form>
```

### Demo with inputs saved in variable

To save the inputs one can use an array `input_numbers` like this:

```js
var input_numbers;

document.forms["myform"].addEventListener('submit',
  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    input_numbers = [...document.querySelectorAll("[type='number']")]
      .map(x => (+x.value));
    const sum = input_numbers
      .reduce((a, c) => a + c);
    alert(`The sum is ${sum}`);
    console.log(input_numbers);
  }
)
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  <input id="num1" type="number" required/>
  <input id="num2" type="number" required/>
  <input type="submit" value="Calculate sum" />
</form>
```

### Some explanations

#### `[...document.querySelectorAll("[type='number']")]`

- `document.querySelectorAll("[type='number']")` selects all inputs of type `'number'` (skipping the `submit` element that's also an inpuy
- `[...X]` converts a NodeList to an Array. This is needed in order to be able to use `map` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55561336/2314737)

#### `.map(x => (+x.value))` and `.reduce((a, c) => a + c)`

- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) are two useful functions for operating on arrays

#### `(+x.value)`

`map(x => (+x.value))` maps each element to its value. But since the value is a string, it's necessary to convert it to a number and for this I used the  ["unary plus" operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus). I could have also used `map(x => parseInt(x.value))`

### No llm

And no, I didn't chat with any llm to write this. Also humans can be pedantic sometimes. Actually, I really appreciate ChatGPT's code explanations so I guess I'm following in its footsteps.

Answer (score -2):

Take input of two numbers from the user. Store it in a variable & print
the sum and product of the two numbers.

Comment: This is a question that looks more like an academic work than a technical one.
We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask