# Displaying the result in Console line by line

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jsfiddle

I have a program that uses json and ajax. When I click the OK button it will display the result in the console Instead of displaying it on the console log, in one line, it needs to be display line per line i tried using the encode function but it still doesn't work.

the siblings should be display on the first page's console
here's  my code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

kyu = (function (document, window, kyu) {   
  var node = Node.prototype,
      nodeList = NodeList.prototype,
      forEach = 'forEach',
      trigger = 'trigger',
      each = [][forEach], 
      dummy = document.createElement('i');

  nodeList[forEach] = each;

  window.on = node.on = function (event, fn) {
    this.addEventListener(event, fn, false);

    return this;
  };

  nodeList.on = function (event, fn) {
    this[forEach](function (el) {
      el.on(event, fn);
    });
    return this;
  };

  window[trigger] = node[trigger] = function (type, data) { 
    var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    event.initEvent(type, true, true);
    event.data = data || {};
    event.eventName = type;
    event.target = this;
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
    return this;
  };

  nodeList[trigger] = function (event) {
    this[forEach](function (el) {
      el[trigger](event);
    });
    return this;
  };

  kyu = function (s) { 
    var r = document.querySelectorAll(s || '?'),
        length = r.length; 
    return length == 1 ? r[0] : r;
  };

  kyu.on = node.on.bind(dummy);
  kyu[trigger] = node[trigger].bind(dummy);

  return kyu;
})(document, this);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="hello"> 
<div id="container">
  siblings:<br>
  <input class="siblings" placeholder="Sibling 1"/><br>
  <input class="siblings" placeholder="Sibling 2"/><br>
  <input class="siblings" placeholder="Sibling 3"/><br/> 
    </div>
    <div id="container1">
      <input id="plus" type="button" value="+">
    <input id="ok"   type="button" value="ok">
    </div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  kyu("#plus").addEventListener("click",function(){ 
    var container=kyu('#container');
    var siblings= kyu('.siblings');
    var count = siblings.length+1;
    var newNode = document.createElement("input"); 
    newNode.classList.add("siblings");
    newNode.placeholder = "siblings" + count; 
    container.appendChild(newNode); 
  }); 
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
  var btn = kyu("#ok");
  btn.onclick = function(){
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var siblings= kyu('.siblings');
     var wew=0;
    var res="";
    var data="{";
    while(siblings.length>wew){
      data+= "'Siblings #" + (wew+1) +"': '"+siblings[wew].value+"', ";
      wew++; 
    }
 data+="}";  
 var po= data.slice(0,-3)+"}"
 //var data={po};
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(req.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
    var wew = JSON.parse(req.responseText); 

      // var new1p= new array('Siblings'=>wew);
      var ll= wew.Siblings; 
        //alert(ll);
     console.log(ll);

      //var mop=(JSON.parse(wew.Siblings));
  }
};
req.open("POST", "poi2.php", true);
req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.send('siblings='+po);
}
</script>
```

and the second page is

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
$result= $siblings; 
$arrayName = array('Siblings'=>$result);

$poi = json_encode($arrayName);
echo $poi;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

While `ll` is a `NodeList`, it can be converted to array and then you can operate on it with array methods.

Like joining it with line breaks:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(ll).join('\r\n')
```

More on [converting to array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3199627/1081234).

Comment: I tried your answer but it goes with an error "Uncaught TypeError: ll.join is not a function
    at XMLHttpRequest.req.onreadystatechange (ajax.php:130)"

Comment: I've updated my answer to convert to array first. You can make it easier for the community to check your code by uploading it to something like jsfiddle in the future

Comment: thank you sir, but the result display the letters line by line, is there a way that it will display in the standard json format?