# animate div height one after the other onload javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, onload

I have managed to get the beginning of my animation working and now I want the rest to animate with a slight delay after each `div` height animation and its causing problems. I've tried using `getElementsByClassName` and that hasn't worked.

I've posted my progress so far [here](https://codepen.io/matt_bart1/pen/pozeNLJ) in codepen.

- Tried using `getElementsByClassName`
- Tried using the `.container` `div`.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      let box = document.getElementById('box')
      box.style.height = "100vh";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="box" id="box">
      box1
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="box2">
      box2
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="box3">
      box3
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="box4">
      box1
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I want each individual element to animate down with delays set to each one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transitionend` event of the first `box`, to start transition of `box2`:

```
window.onload = function () {
  const box = document.getElementById('box');

  box.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
    document.getElementById('box2').style.height = "100vh";
  }, {once: true});

  box.style.height = "100vh";
}
```

In case you want to start 2nd animation before 1st one finished you could use `setTimeout` function with desired delay:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  const box = document.getElementById('box');

  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById('box2').style.height = "100vh";
  }, 200);

  box.style.height = "100vh";
}
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you so much this worked really well. Is there any way to manually set the delay so the animation starts a little faster ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
window.onload = function () {
  var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  for(var i = 0; i < box.length; i++)
  {
     box[i].style.height = "100vh";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There you have it. A code to animate each of your boxes one after the other.

Notice I had to convert your node list to an array first and then reverse the array. This is in order to be able to pop elements from the array and use the lenght of the array to terminate the recursive function `animateBoxes()`.

I used the `setTimeout()` function to execute the recursive function 1 second at a time. You can modify the time parameter to your need.

The major advantage of this method is that it can **automatically** animate any number of boxes.

```js
window.onload = function () { 
    let boxes = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".box")).reverse();
    animateBoxes(boxes);

    function animateBoxes(boxes) {
        if(boxes.length) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                boxes.pop().style.height = "100vh";
                animateBoxes(boxes);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: green;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

#box, #box2, #box3, #box4 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    transition: 1s;
}

#box {
    background: red;
}

#box2 {
    background: purple;
}

#box3 {
    background: orange;
}

#box4 {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container"> 
    <div class="box" id="box"> box1 </div> 
    <div class="box" id="box2"> box2 </div> 
    <div class="box" id="box3"> box3 </div> 
    <div class="box" id="box4"> box4 </div> 
</div>
```