# Native Javascript multple events to multiple elements

Tags: javascript

I have below code

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName("numericOnly")].forEach(node => {
                console.log(node)
                node.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
                    console.log(event)
                }, false);
                node.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
                    console.log(event)
                }, false);
            });
```

But i want to try some thing like below which is not working

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName("numericOnly")].forEach(node => {
                console.log(node)
                node.addEventListener('keypress,keyup', function (event) {
                    console.log(event)
                }, false);
          });
```

Also trying like below but that is nested

```
 ["keypress", "keyup"].forEach(function (event) {
                    [...document.querySelectorAll('.numericOnly')].forEach(node => {
                        console.log(node)
                        node.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
                            console.log(event)
                        }, false);
                    })
                });
```

Anyway to get this without nested some thing

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName("numericOnly")].forEach(node => {
                console.log(node)
                node.addEventListener('keypress,keyup', function (event) {
                    console.log(event)
                }, false);
          });
```

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with your first example?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what you are looking for? You can create a wrapper like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/2nwpxefc/1/)** or put the entire code in a generic function that accepts selector and attaches events like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/2nwpxefc/4/)**

Comment: Your 3rd snippet would have worked if you used `event` in place of hard-coded "keypress". (Not withstanding you'd used the variable `event` twice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), you cannot have more than one event name attached in one call.

You can however create a utility function that can generically work for any combination for a given eveny list

#### Idea

- Create a function that accepts following:

  - **Selector:** This will allow you to fetch elements based on any attribute.
  - **EventList:** This is a comma separated list of events you need to attach.
  - **Handler:** This is the actual common handler for events passed
  - **Option:** To decide when to execute the said event (*bubbling/capture phase*).

Following is a sample of such function with possible call

```js
function registerEventHandler(selector, events, handler, option) {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)].forEach(node => {
    events.split(',').forEach(function(eventName) {
      node.addEventListener(eventName, handler, option);
    })
  });
}

const handler = function(event) {
  console.log(event)
};

registerEventHandler('.numericOnly', 'keypress,keyup', handler, false);
registerEventHandler('.numericAndAlphabet', 'keypress,change', handler, false)
```

Comment: **Note:** If you think there is anything incorrect/ not required in this answer, please do share your suggestion along with your vote

Comment: Could you please let me know y below link is not work

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam could you please inform me what you are expecting?

Comment: That is fine now.

Comment: One request could you please let me know work of spread operator here [...document.getElementsByClassName("numericOnly")], becuase without this it was not working

Comment: Its just converting NodeList to Array. You can alternatively try `Array.from` or `Array.prototype.slice.call(List)`. For more info, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199588/fastest-way-to-convert-javascript-nodelist-to-array

Answer (score -1):

If your question is how to bind an eventhandler to multiple events the answer is: either you don't or you do it in the way you call 'nested':

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.numeric-only').forEach((node) => {
  ['keypress', 'keyup'].forEach((event) => {
    console.log(`binding ${event} to`, node)
    node.addEventListener(event, () => {
      console.log(event)
    }, false);
  })
});
```

```html
<input class="numeric-only">
```

Comment: Isn't that covered in OP's question? 3rd snippet?

Comment: @Rajesh Only similar, some changes applied to get it running.

Comment: The point was, OP's code is already working. So switching the loop will not change anything.

Comment: This is I covered, doesn't mean minor changes, question is , Is there any way to bind multiple events to multiple elements without nested loop or binding it separately

Comment: @Rajesh The code he called "nested" does not work in the desired way, as it binds only a keypress

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam As I said: No, there is no other way.

Comment: @Joschi, Could you please check why below code is not working

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam You missed a preventDefault to stop the event https://jsfiddle.net/ndrj0m3p/

Comment: I tried that ,but seems it was breaking somewhere. Thanks its working, one more request could you please let me know work of spread operator here [...document.getElementsByClassName("numericOnly")], becuase without this it was not working