# Get span elements within div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html code:

```
<div id="id0" class="class0">
    <span> "1" </span>
    <span> "2" </span>
    <span> "3" </span>
</div>
```

The question is how can I get 1,2,3 as a list using javascript?

I tried: document.getElementById and document.getElementsByClassName
But none works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map` and then remove the `quoted marks` to get only the `number list`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="id0" class="class0">
    <span> "1" </span>
    <span> "2" </span>
    <span> "3" </span>
  </div>
  
  <script>
    console.clear();
    const selectors = document.querySelectorAll('#id0 > span');
    const list = [...selectors].map(span => parseInt(span.innerText.replace(/"/g,"")));
    console.log(list)
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

The function [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is your friend.

```js
document.getElementById("id0").querySelectorAll('span').forEach(element => {
  console.log (element);
})
```

```html
<div id="id0" class="class0">
    <span> "1" </span>
    <span> "2" </span>
    <span> "3" </span>
</div>
```

Comment: how does this match the output of the op?

Comment: @EugenSunic What is your problem? The question was "how can I get a list" and `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`.

Comment: obviously you don't read the questoin well `The question is how can I get 1,2,3 as a list using javascript?`, check the most voted answer

Comment: @EugenSunic What do you want to say? You think we should close the question, because it is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199588/fastest-way-to-convert-javascript-nodelist-to-array) one?

Comment: Let's see what the OP says, because if he wants want the most voted answer provides then it's not a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map()` on `children` on container div

```js
const cont = document.getElementById('id0');
const res = [...cont.children].map(x => x.innerHTML);
console.log(res)
```

```html
<div id="id0" class="class0">
    <span> "1" </span>
    <span> "2" </span>
    <span> "3" </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the elements using `document.getElementById` and `document.getElementsByTagName`, then iterate through them and add them to the list. Use `textContent` and `innerText` to obtain the text of the span element.

```js
var spans = document.getElementById('id0').getElementsByTagName('span');
var obj = [];
for (var i = 0, l = spans.length; i < l; i++) {
  obj.push(parseInt(spans[i].textContent.replace(/"/g,"")) || parseInt(spans[i].innerText.replace(/"/g,"")));
}
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<div id="id0" class="class0">
    <span> "1" </span>
    <span> "2" </span>
    <span> "3" </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I mention the process here for you-
First, get the div from the document- `const div = document.getElementById("id0");`, you can do this using other methods,
then get all the children of the div, you may do this by `const spans = div.children;`, look now **spans** is HTMLCollection (which is iterable) containing all the spans. Now you iterate over each span and get your textContent and change them using regex/others as you want and put them in a list or others.

The best way to learn from others is to understand the code before copying them.

`

```
const div = document.getElementById("id0");
const spans = div.children;
for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  // here you get each textContent by spans[i].textContent
}
```

`