# Array.some() is not a Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, methods, typeerror

I have a problem with the method array.some() in JavaScript.
I have an html-code:

```
<div class="list">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item selected"></div>
</div>
```

And I'm trying to find one element of array which contains class-name "selected".

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

items.some(item => {
 if (item.classList.contains('selected')) { console.log(true); }
 else { console.log(false); }
});
```

But all what I get is this error: "Uncaught TypeError: items.some is not a function"
Can someone tell me, why the method Array.some() doesn't work for div array? Thank you

Comment: #remark, I know, I typed incorrect, "contains" instead "containd", but it's not the point

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is an array method but `items` here is not an array but a collection of nodes, better known as [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). So, we first need it to convert it into an array like:

```
const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')];
```

For more info:

- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

DEMO:

```js
const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')];

items.some(item => {
  if (item.classList.contains('selected')) {
    console.log(true, item);
  } else {
    console.log(false, item);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item selected"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) witch don't implement `some` method

Use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert `NodeList` to `Array`

You can find other [methods to convert `NodeList` to `Array`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199588/fastest-way-to-convert-javascript-nodelist-to-array)

```
const items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.item'));

items.some(item => {
 if (item.classList.contains('selected')) { console.log(true); }
 else { console.log(false); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) function returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an array.

Convert it to an array using `Array.from(nodelist)`.