# Changing Drop Down Boxes To Radio Buttons For Quiz

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Code newbie here!

I've managed to put together a form which tallies up a user's score based on their selections. And it works!

Here's my code:

```js
function finalScore(round) {

  var correct = 0;

  var selectValue;

  var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("question");

  var numOfQuestions = questions.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) { //begin for loop

    //get the value of the select element
    selectValue = questions[i].options[questions[i].selectedIndex].value;

    //if the value equals right
    if (selectValue === "one") { //begin if then

      //increment the correct variable
      correct = correct + 1;

    } else if (selectValue === "two") {

      correct = correct + 2;

    } else if (selectValue === "three") {

      correct = correct + 3;

    } else if (selectValue === "four") {

      correct = correct + 4;

    }

  } //end for loop

  alert(correct);

  if (round === false) {
    //get the percentage of correct answers(not rounded)
    document.getElementById("scoreDisplay").innerHTML = correct;
  } else {

    //display the rounded value
    document.getElementById("scoreDisplay").innerHTML = correct;

  } //end if then else

} //end function
```

```html
How Old Are You?
<select class="question" id="1howold">
  <option value="three">19 - 26</option>
  <option value="four">27 - 36</option>
  <option value="two">37 - 40</option>
  <option value="one">41+</option>
</select><br /><br /> What's Your Relationship Status?
<select class="question" id="2relationshipstatus">
  <option value="four">Single and excited to see what’s out there.</option>
  <option value="three">Recently single and emotionally destroyed.</option>
  <option value="two">Got some casual things on the go, not looking for anything too serious.</option>
  <option value="one">In a committed relationship and only taking this quiz for the lols.</option>
</select><br /><br /> Where Is Your Location?
<select class="question" id="3location">
  <option value="four">Location Independent</option>
  <option value="three">London/The UK</option>
  <option value="two">Europe</option>
  <option value="one">Elsewhere</option>
</select><br /><br />

<button type="button" onclick="finalScore(true)">Submit</button>

<div id="scoreDisplay">score goes here</div>
```

See the JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tm3o5g0k/

However, I've realised I need to switch these to radio buttons due to the length of some of the options. I've tried so many methods and I keep making a mess! Surely there's an easy way to do this that I'm overlookng?

Thanks! :)

Comment: You've shown your code handling the scoring, what's the problem you're having with converting the `<select>` and `<option>` elements to `<input>` elements?

Comment: I did try this but I guess the javascript needs some tweaking? I can't seem to work it out.
Probably this line?
`selectValue =  questions[i].options[questions[i].selectedIndex].value;`

Comment: But that line has to do with adding up the scores (or, rather, finding the selected `<option>`), rather than converting the `<option>` elements into `<input>` elements. Am I misunderstanding the nature of your question? Is your problem with finding the selected options, and then finding the score? Or is it with converting `<option>` into `<input>`?

Comment: Based on my understanding of what you're trying to do this is the best I could come up with: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/njum1k5v/1/

Comment: This is perfect! You're a genius! Sorry I'm so bad at this, most of my code was copy and paste so I didn't know what was going on. Really appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code – and problem description – in your question, and comments to the question, I've developed the following solution. The assumptions I've made are:

1. you want to convert the `<option>` elements to `<input type="radio" />` elements, and
2. you want to determine a total-score based on the value assigned to each of the `<input>` elements.

With that in mind I've adjusted the HTML to better fit the identified assumptions and their requirements:

1. the value of each `option` element is the numeric equivalent of the score, in order that they can be more easily used in calculations, therefore `value="four"` has become `value="1"`,
2. the `textNode` prior to each of the `<select>` elements has been converted to a `<legend>` in order that each 'group' of `<input>` elements can be visually recognised as a group,
3. I've removed the number – which seems largely irrelevant – from the `id` of each `<select>`, while under HTML 5 it's valid to have an `id` starting with a numeral it's historically problematic to select such an `id` via CSS as the number is required to be explicitly escaped,
4. I've also assigned a `name` property to the `<select>` elements, this is because the `name` is required to correctly pass values to the server in the event that the results should be stored in a database, and also for `<input type="radio">` elements to act as a mutually-exclusive group (so only *one* `<input>` can be selected at a time from the related elements) a `name` property must be assigned to identify that relationship. As such it made sense to add the `name` to the `<select>` prior to manipulation rather than relying on an auto-generated `name`, which would, or could, lead to server-side storage problems.

With all that said, one approach to solving your problems is below:

```js
// declaring the functions as constants, using 'const';
// variables declared with const cannot be reassigned,
// though if the variable is an Object or Array the
// properties, or contents, of that Object or Array can
// be changed/updated later:
const selectToRadio = (selectSelector) => {

        // within the function body we retrieve all relevant elements
        // using document.querySelectorAll(), passing the CSS selector
        // supplied to the function; then that iterable static
        // NodeList is converted to an Array using the spread syntax:
        const selects = [...document.querySelectorAll(selectSelector)],
        
              // we create basic elements:
              input = document.createElement('input'),
              label = document.createElement('label'),
              span = document.createElement('span');

    // set the type of the created <input> element:
    input.type = 'radio';

    // here we take the Array of Nodes and iterate over that
    // Array using Array.prototype.forEach() with an Arrow
    // function:
    selects.forEach(
    
      // 'sel' is a reference to the current <select> element
      // from the Array of <select> elements over which we're
      // iterating:
      (sel) => {
      
        // here we assign the property-value of the 'name' property
        // of the <select> element as the 'groupName' of the <inpu>
        // elements we're creating:
        let groupName = sel.name,
        
            // here we retrieve all descendant <option> elements
            // from the current <select> element, using
            // Element.querySelectorAll() and, again, creating
            // an Array - with the spread operator - of the
            // resulting iterable NodeList:
            options = [...sel.querySelectorAll('option')],
            
            // here we create a documentFragment() so all the
            // created elements can be appended at the same time:
            fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
            
        // here we again use Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over
        // the Array of <option> elements:
        options.forEach(
        
          // 'opt' (these variables can be named whatever you like, so
          // so long as it's a valid variable-name within the naming
          // rules of JavaScript) is a reference to the current <option>
          // of the Array of <option> elements over which we're
          // iterating:
          (opt) => {
          
            // here we create clones of the various elements we
            // created earlier (rather than creating the same
            // type of element multiple times in each iteration
            // of the loop):
            let inputClone = input.cloneNode(),
                labelClone = label.cloneNode(),
                spanClone = span.cloneNode();
              
            // here we set the 'name' and 'value' properties of the
            // cloned <input>:
            inputClone.name = groupName;
            inputClone.value = opt.value;
            
            // we use the Element.classList API to add the 'answer'
            // class-name to the created element:
            inputClone.classList.add('answer');
            
            // we set the textContent of the created <span> to be
            // equal to the text from the current <option>:
            spanClone.textContent = opt.text;

            // we use the parentNode.append() method to append the
            // cloned <input> and the cloned <span> elements to
            // the cloned <label>:
            labelClone.append(inputClone, spanClone);
            
            // then we append the cloned <label> to the documentFragment:
            fragment.append(labelClone);
          });
          
        // we use parentNode.insertBefore() method to insert the
        // documentFragment into the DOM before the current <select>
        // element:
        sel.parentNode.insertBefore(fragment, sel);
        
        // and then use childNode.remove() method to remove
        // the current <select> element - and its descendants -
        // from the DOM:
        sel.remove();
      });
  },
  score = () => {
    // here we use the same approach as above to create an Array of
    // element-nodes that have the 'answer' class-name and are also checked:
    const answers = [...document.querySelectorAll('.answer:checked')],
          // here we take the answers Array, and then call:
          result = answers
            // Array.prototype.map() to create a new Array based on the
            // contents of the current Array; here that new Array is
            // an Array of Numbers:
            .map(
              // we again use Arrow syntax for the anonymous function,
              // here 'el' is a reference to the current checked <input>
              // element; the function body (the single line following
              // the '=>' characters) simply returns the value of the
              // checked <option> parsed as a Number in base 10. Any
              // attribute-value (from which the value property is
              // derived is returned as a String from JavaScript, which
              // is why we're parsing it to a Number):
              (el) => parseInt(el.value, 10))

            // we then pass the Array of Numbers to the
            // Array.prototype.reduce() function in order to reduce
            // the chained Array to a single result; again we use an
            // Arrow function syntax; here the body of the function
            // is taking the previously-held (or default) value ('a') and
            // adding it to the value of the current Array-element (b);
            // the '0' at the end of the function is the default-value with
            // which the reduce function starts:
            .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
            
    // we then find the element that will show the result, and update its
    // text-content to be equal to the resulting score:
    document.querySelector('#scoreDisplay').textContent = result;
    
    // here we return the result to the calling context in the event you want
    // to also store or otherwise manipulate the derived score:
    return result;
  };

// here we call the selectToRadio() function, passing in an
// appropriate CSS selector:
selectToRadio('select');

// here we retrieve the first or only <button> element in the document:
document.querySelector('button')
  
  // and use EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the named score()
  // function (note the deliberate lack of parentheses) as the
  // event-handler for the 'click' event:
  .addEventListener('click', score);
```

```css
fieldset {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}

legend {
  padding: 0 0.6em;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0 0.6em;
  margin: 0.3em 0;
}

input+span {
  border-radius: 0.6em;
}

input:checked+span {
  color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>How old are you?</legend>

    <select class="question" id="howold" name="ageRange">
      <option value="3">19 - 26</option>
      <option value="4">27 - 36</option>
      <option value="2">37 - 40</option>
      <option value="1">41+</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>What's your relationship status?</legend>
    <select class="question" id="relationshipstatus" name="relationshipStatus">
      <option value="4">Single and excited to see what’s out there.</option>
      <option value="3">Recently single and emotionally destroyed.</option>
      <option value="2">Got some casual things on the go, not looking for anything too serious.</option>
      <option value="1">In a committed relationship and only taking this quiz for the lols.</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>What is your location?</legend>
    <select class="question" id="location" name="location">
      <option value="4">Location Independent</option>
      <option value="3">London/The UK</option>
      <option value="2">Europe</option>
      <option value="1">Elsewhere</option>
    </select>

  </fieldset>
  <button type="button">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="scoreDisplay"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/njum1k5v/1/).

In the above code we used the following approach:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('CSS-selector')]
```

to efficiently create Arrays from the NodeList result of the `document.querySelectorAll()`, this is unnecessary in the `selectToRadio()` function as we only use `Array.prototype.forEach()` which could be replaced with `NodeList.prototype.forEach()` with no changes to the syntax.

However in the composition of the functions I hadn't entirely decided how I was going to implement the code in advance, so I converted the `NodeList`s to Arrays simply in order that I might be able to use other Array methods – such as `Array.prototype.map()`, `Array.prototype.filter()` – as I did in the `score()` function.

I don't believe it will increase efficiency by much, if at all, but if you'd rather not waste processing time converting a `NodeList` into an Array then simply convert the following lines:

```
const selects = [...document.querySelectorAll(selectSelector)],
```

and:

```
options = [...sel.querySelectorAll('option')],
```

into:

```
const selects = document.querySelectorAll(selectSelector),
```

and:

```
options = sel.querySelectorAll('option'),
```

other than that no changes need to be made and when, for example:

```
selects.forEach(
  (sel) => ....
```

is called the JavaScript engine will use `NodeList.prototype.forEach()` automatically in place of `Array.prototype.forEach()` (proof of concept: [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/njum1k5v/2/)).

In the `score()` function, however, I do use the other methods of the `Array.prototype` which are not translated to, or available on, NodeLists so that must remain an Array.

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
- [`ChildNode.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove).
- [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).
- [`document.createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement).
- [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).
- [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).
- [`ParentNode.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append).

Bibliography:

- "[Fastest way to convert JavaScript NodeList to [an] Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199588/fastest-way-to-convert-javascript-nodelist-to-array)"
- "[How to find the sum of an Array of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)"