# Why does array.prototype.slice() with no arguments change my output?

Tags: javascript

I am doing this challenge on leetcode.

- Challenge: 
  https://leetcode.com/problems/relative-ranks/submissions/

Why is it that, this answer is accepted?

**My Code:**

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {string[]}
 */
var findRelativeRanks = function(nums) {
    const map = new Map();
    let result;
    nums
        .slice()
        .sort((a, b) => b - a)
        .forEach((num, i) => map.set(num, (i + 1).toString()));
    result = nums.map(num => {
        switch(map.get(num)) {
            case "1":
                return "Gold Medal";
            case "2":
                return "Silver Medal";
            case "3":
                return "Bronze Medal";
            default:
                return map.get(num);
        }
    })
    return result;
};
```

But if I just remove `.slice()`, some test cases fail. Why?

Comment: The actual code should be posted **here**, not on jsbin or another site like that. Stack Overflow has all the same facilities.

Comment: You may check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286950/using-the-javascript-slice-method-with-no-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slice returns a shallow copy of the array.

```
nums.slice().sort(/* ... */).forEach()
```

will

1. copy the array with slice
2. sort the array
3. iterated the sorted, copied array.

However, further accesses to 'nums' will not be sorted because the copy was not saved anywehre.