# Object.prototype.toString.call(), Why in the most part of examples it's used call() instead apply?

Tags: javascript, callback, call

I'm very curious concerning because when we access to high level functions in the most part of examples always it's used the `call()` method.

examples:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call();
Array.prototype.slice.call();
```

It's for convention or there are other reasons?

Comment: Those examples might not have required to pass arguments as an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically `call()` expects the arguments needs to be passed in a comma separated format, whereas `apply()` expects the arguments as an array. So the examples that you have seen might not needed the arguments to be passed as an array. This is a matter of choice,

A simple example:

```
Math.max.call(Math, 1,2,3,4,5);
//is same as 
Math.max.apply(Math, [1,2,3,4,5]);
```

And in some special cases the `this` argument for `call`/`apply` will be passed as an `object` and the original arguments will be ignored. Like,

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("div")
Array.prototype.slice.call(x);
//This will convert the nodeList to an array.
```

The above sample will access the `length` property of the passed `this` (a `nodeList`) and will construct a new array and return it. You have to read the algorithm of [`slice`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.10) to know more about it. And [this is how the slice will works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36018463/1209018) internally, An answer by me.

Answer (score 1):

Both does the same, in one you can `pass comma separated arguments` and the other one `array`. I don't see any other difference, if in `bind` you could use the returned function at a `later context` with the inner function still having the outer function's `scope`.

Answer (score 1):

`.call` is equivalent to `.apply` as long as you don't pass arguments other then `this` (i.e. the first argument). Chosing one over another is just a convention.