# Javascript unshift() on html element array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs and I have this line of code:

```
// Get our elements
var elements = angular.element(options.animation.element).children().children();
```

with this collection I would like to take a certain amount of elements and move them from the end to the front.
I tried like this:

```
var stop = elements.length - options.itemsToShow,
    elementsToMove = elements.splice(stop, options.itemsToShow);

elements.unshift(elementsToMove);
```

but I get an error stating

> TypeError: elements.unshift is not a function

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: `elements` probably isn't an array, but an array-like.

Comment: Could you try by replacing the  `unshift` statement with `elements.splice(0, 0, elementsToMove);`?

Answer (score 2):

`elements` is not a `array` to apply `array` methods. Use [**`Array.from`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) over `array-like` collection.

> *The `Array.from()` method creates a new Array instance from an `array-like` or `iterable object`.*

```
Array.from(elements).unshift(elementsToMove);
```

*Note:* Also consider using [*Polyfill*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill) due to lack of [*Browser compatibility*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility)

**Or** [`[].slice.call`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125714/explanation-of-slice-call-in-javascript) could be used as well!

Comment: using angular. will any of these actually update the DOM? Creating a new array won't work because angular works with 2 way binding, so i need to actually modify the collection itself

Comment: I am unable to relate things with `2-way binding` with `new array`.. Have you tried this solution ?