# Strange behaviour of splice method in the context of childnodes

Tags: javascript, arrays

We have one ul element with four li child element contained within
then lets say the following code is executed in the console

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
a.childNodes.splice(1, 2, "abc", "cde");
```

Then the error pops up with the message:

```
TypeError: a.childNodes.splice is not a function
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: `a.childNodes` does not return an array but `array-like` object...

Comment: Use [__`Array.from`__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) over `array-like` collection. __Or__ [`[].slice.call`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125714/explanation-of-slice-call-in-javascript) could be used as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Node.childnodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) returns a [`Node List`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which is not an array in JavaScript. So you cannot apply `splice` to it.

As MDN notes,

> ### Why is NodeList not an Array?
>
> NodeList are used very much like arrays and it's tempting to invoke
>   Array.prototype methods on them, however NodeList objects don't have
>   any of the familiar Array methods.

A work around will be to make it an array like this.

```
var nodesArray = [].slice.call(a);
//now call the splice method.
nodesArray.childNodes.splice(1, 2, "abc", "cde");
```

Comment: OP is talking about `Node.childNodes`

Comment: oops!! so what does the object called which is returned by    getelementsByTagNAme

Comment: @Andrew – It is called [`live collection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)

Comment: i think getElementsByTagName and a.childNodes returns the same object whatever the object is called. sorry i am a newbie @Rayon

Comment: one returns HTML collection and other returns nodelist

Comment: @naveen – You have justified why it is not working.. But what about solution ?

Comment: i am talking about the object name like the object name array. is that it??

Comment: @Andrew – It is `array-like` Collection/Nodelist

Comment: @Rayon you have already pointed the solution in your comment :)

Comment: @Rayon does these array like collection has its unique names or "array-like" is itself the name for these.

Comment: @Andrew There is no specific name as far as my knowledge is concerned... But array-like is good enogh name I feel...