# How do I get the same output using the closure concept

Tags: javascript

this code displays the helper text whenever a user focuses on any of the input fields. My issue is I want to write the code having the same functionality but using the closure concept. Idk if this code already uses closure concept, if it does please tell me where and if it doesn't please tell me how do you do it using the closure concept.

```js
var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.form-container p input:not([type="submit"])');

for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
  var inputField = allInputs[i];
  var inputFieldId = inputField.id;
  var getInput = document.getElementById(inputFieldId);
  getInput.addEventListener('focus', helperNote, false);
}

function helperNote(e) {
  var helperNode = document.querySelector('.form-container #helperNote');
  var helperNote = document.createTextNode('Please input the ' + e.target.name);
  //console.dir (helperNote);
  helperNode.textContent = helperNote.data;
  helperNode.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-container">
    <p>Fill The Form Below</p>
    <p id="helperNote">Helper note Appears Here</p>
    <p>
      <label>Email :</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Username :</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Name :</label>
      <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Age :</label>
      <input type="number" name="age" id="age">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>City :</label>
      <input type="text" name="City" id="City">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="sign-up">
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You don't need to create a text node just to extract the string again. You can set `helperNode.textContent` to the value of your string directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't currently make use of any closures, but you could use one in order to replace your `for` loop with a `forEach` function that accepts a callback. This will eliminate your need for the `e` parameter, because you will have access to the `getInput` variable in the surrounding lexical scope. `NodeList` usually has a built-in [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method, but it's not available on IE, so you could use one of [these alternatives](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/).

I noticed you had a lot of unnecessary code here, so I've removed it as well.

```js
var forEach = function(array, callback, scope) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    callback.call(scope, array[i], i, array);
  }
};

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:not([type="submit"])');
var helperNote = document.getElementById('helperNote');

forEach(inputs, function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    helperNote.textContent = 'Please input the ' + input.name;
  });
});
```

```css
label { display: block; margin: 5px 0; }
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <p>Fill The Form Below</p>
  <p id="helperNote">Helper note appears here</p>
  <label>Email: <input type="email" name="email"></label>
  <label>Username: <input type="text" name="username"></label>
  <label>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></label>
  <label>Age: <input type="number" name="age"></label>
  <label>City: <input type="text" name="city"></label>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

Comment: I did not know that IE didn't allow `forEach` on `NodeList`s. It doesn't do `Array.from()` either, so that sucks (as usual).

Comment: @FredGandt Yeah, one typical workaround I've seen is to use `[].slice.call(arrayLike)` in place of `Array.from()`

Comment: You might also want to add a note about the _improper_ `<label>` usage, and show how it _should be done_. Ah yes - `[].slice.call...` the bad old days just won't go away!

Answer (score 1):

## `focus` on functionality

Rather than worrying about the technical nomenclature of the syntax, concentrate on the functionality.

Use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over the `<input>` elements, adding event listeners as it goes, that, when triggered, apply the desired change to the `textContent` of the `#helperNote`.

Take note in [4castle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5743988/4castle)'s answer of Internet Explorer's current lack of support for `forEach()` on a `NodeList`.
And I thank him for reminding me about [`[].slice.call()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125714/explanation-of-slice-call-in-javascript), which I've used below to transform the [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) returned by `querySelectorAll()` into an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) which IE will allow `forEach` on (since it also doesn't currently support [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)).

I've added [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) handling to reset the `#helperNote` when the `input`s lose `focus`, and used some [nifty CSS goodies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr) for fun.

```js
const helperNote = document.querySelector( "#helperNote" );

[].slice.call( // No thanks to Internet Explorer >.<
  document.querySelectorAll( "form input:not([type=submit])" )
).forEach( element => {
  element.addEventListener( "focus", () => {
    helperNote.setAttribute( "data-info", element.name );
  } );
  element.addEventListener( "blur", () => {
    helperNote.setAttribute( "data-info", "details" );
  } );
} );
```

```css
label {
  display: table; /* block layout with inline qualities */
  margin: .5em 0;
}
#helperNote::before {
  content: "Please input your " attr( data-info );
}
#helperNote[data-info=details]::after {
  content: " below.";
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <p id="helperNote" data-info="details"></p>
  <label>Email :<input type="email" name="email" id="email"></label>
  <label>Username :<input type="text" name="username" id="username"></label>
  <label>Name :<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name"></label>
  <label>Age :<input type="number" name="age" id="age"></label>
  <label>City :<input type="text" name="City" id="City"></label>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="sign-up">
</form>
```