# Javascript - For Loop for maxLength on P Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, maxlength

I have this solution here that limits the characters of the selected P tag to 125 characters, however it only applies to the first child in the loop, how can I edit the following code to work in a For loop? I've attempted some solutions with some jQuery but haven't found any to work.

Appreciate the help!

```
function truncateText(selector, maxLength) {

    var element = document.querySelector(".hp-um-description")
     for (element = element) {
        var truncated = element.innerText;

        if (truncated.length > maxLength) {
            truncated = truncated.substr(0,maxLength) + '...';
        }
        return truncated;  
     }
    }

    $(".hp-um-description").each(function(){
      document.querySelector('.hp-um-description').innerText = truncateText('.hp-um-description', 125);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) to avoid loops and achieve this quite cleanly.

```js
function truncateText(selector, maxLength) {
  $(selector).text((i, txt) => txt.length > maxLength ? txt.substr(0,maxLength) + "..." : txt);
};

truncateText(".hp-um-description", 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="hp-um-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris feugiat ipsum massa, et sagittis enim tempus id. Mauris nisl turpis, pellentesque scelerisque congue nec, faucibus vel arcu.</p>

<p class="hp-um-description"> Fusce id ultrices nibh. Suspendisse sit amet felis lobortis, rhoncus ex eu, fringilla lacus.</p>

<p class="hp-um-description">Suspendisse sit amet felis lobortis, rhoncus ex eu, fringilla lacus. Duis vehicula placerat sapien, ac consectetur dolor egestas eget.</p>
```

The code above will loop through all elements satisfied by the selector and apply a function. This line detemines if it should be truncated or not:

```
     txt.length > maxLength ?    txt.substr(0,maxLength) + "..."     :         txt
//(If length exceeds maxlength)     (truncate and add ...)         (else)    (leave the text as-is)
```

---

**If you'd like to be able to truncate `string` values as well**, you can use the code below instead:

```js
String.prototype.truncate = function(maxLength) {
  var t = this.toString();
  return t.length > maxLength ? t.substr(0, maxLength) + "..." : t;
};

function truncateText(selector, maxLength) {
  $(selector).text((i, txt) => txt.truncate(maxLength));
};

//Truncate an existing element's text
truncateText(".hp-um-description", 100);

//Truncate a string
console.log("This is a long string that exceeds 30 characters.".truncate(30));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="hp-um-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris feugiat ipsum massa, et sagittis enim tempus id. Mauris nisl turpis, pellentesque scelerisque congue nec, faucibus vel arcu.</p>

<p class="hp-um-description"> Fusce id ultrices nibh. Suspendisse sit amet felis lobortis, rhoncus ex eu, fringilla lacus.</p>

<p class="hp-um-description">Suspendisse sit amet felis lobortis, rhoncus ex eu, fringilla lacus. Duis vehicula placerat sapien, ac consectetur dolor egestas eget.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Works like a charm, I thought jQuery would be a good way to avoid complication. Cheers :)

Comment: how can I incorporate this into a .text() field? For example:

<p class="block um-desp">' + $(this).find("attribute[id='19']").text() + '</p>

Comment: @JLawless The function I wrote above will only work with elements that are already on the page. If you're looking to truncate a string, I can edit my question to provide an additional method.

Comment: @JLawless If  you take a look at my update, the second example adds a `String.truncate` function that you can use on any string. Applying the function to your comment would look like this: `$(this).find("attribute[id=19"]).text().truncate(100)`. That said, not sure what exactly `attribute[id=19]` is supposed to be doing. If you're looking for an element by ID, you shouldn't need to use `.find` or attributes - simply `$("#19").text()` would work.

Comment: the attribute is targeting an XML Element by it's ID as I'm parsing information from an XML into a displayable format with jQuery. You're update worked like a treat, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function truncateText(element, maxLength) {
    var truncated = element.innerText;
    if (truncated.length > maxLength)
        truncated = truncated.substr(0,maxLength) + '...';
    return truncated;
}
$(function() {
    $(".hp-um-description").each(function(i,obj) {
        obj.innerText = truncateText(obj, 125);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this also did the job well!

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JavaScript you could approach this in the following fashion...

```
var maxLength = 125;

/* select elements as an Array 
   and iterate with Array.forEach() */

[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".hp-um-description")).forEach(function(el) {
    /* 'el' => each ".hp-um-description" element */

    /* attempt truncation */
    el.innerText = el.innerText.slice(0, maxLength);
    /* if el.innerText.length is shorter than
       'maxLength' the whole String will be returned (unchanged),
       otherwise the String will be truncated (modified) */
});
```

The equivalent of the `el` variable in the JQuery `.each()` function is bound to the callback's `this` property, like so...

```
$(".hp-um-description").each(function() {
    /* $(this) => each ".hp-um-description" element */

    var el = $(this);

    /* apply the same conditions as above */
    el.text( el.text().slice(0, maxLength) ); 
});
```

Hope that helped :D

See:

- [$.text() @ JQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [$.each() @ JQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/each/)
- [String.slice() @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)
- [Array.forEach() @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Array.slice.call() @ StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2125746/4746328)