# [].slice.call() pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

[Bootstrap 5 Javascript examples sometimes show code like](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/#via-javascript):

```
var collapseElementList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.collapse'))
```

Why isn't this just:

```
var collapseElementList = document.querySelectorAll('.collapse')
```

What is `[].slice.call()` doing exactly? I don't understand why you'd `slice` on an empty array, and then I have no idea what `call` is doing there. What would be the problem with the obvious way to do this, the second way above?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125714/explanation-of-slice-call-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

`querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, which is a collection, but not an array.

`[].slice.call` turns an array-like collection into an array proper. It will allow you to use array methodss on it, eg:

```
var collapseElementList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.collapse'));
const textsOfCollapsedElements = collapseElementList.map(elm => elm.textContent);
```

Otherwise, if you don't convert it to an array first, you won't be able to use array methods on it.

It's probably most important for `forEach`. Newer browsers support `NodeList.prototype.forEach`, but it hasn't been with us *that* long. In contrast, `Array.prototype.forEach` has existed forever. So turning the collection into an array allows for `forEach` to be called on it, even on obsolete browsers that don't support `NodeList.prototype.forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

It's an idiom for turning anything array-ish (in this case a DOM NodeList) into a real Array by exploiting the fact that `Array::slice` can work on anything that's iterable and has a `.length`  property.

The modern idiom is `Array.from(...)`.